# Tips for golfing in Tcl

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in Tcl? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to Tcl (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`lmap`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lmap.htm) instead [`foreach`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm). This requires Tcl 8.6.

The syntax is the same, but `lmap` returns a list with the result of each loop.

Answer (score 4):

Subcommands and options can (usually) be abbreviated. This can save quite a bit, but you *must* test as not everything can be shortened this way (`regsub`'s options can't, for example).

You can then use this with the magic of `namespace` to do some truly evil things. Consider this:

```
namespace exp *;namespace en cr -c ?
```

After that, `?` is now a magical command that lets you abbreviate any global Tcl command, and all without the nasty uncertainty of messing around with `unknown`.

Answer (score 4):

On my answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107557/29325 I can demonstrate:

1. Usually `set j 0;while \$j<$n;{...;incr j}` is shorter than the equivalent `for {set j 0} {$j<$n} {incr j} {...}`
2. When the looping variable begins at 1, we can do the increment as part of the `while` test condition, avoiding to write before `set i 1` unnecessarily: `while {[incr i]<=$n} {...}` instead of `set i 1;while \$i<=$n;{...;incr i}`

**ATTENTION**: One can only do 2. in the case of an outer loop! I could not apply it to my `j` variable as it needs to be reset to 1 in the outside of its own inner loop! And `incr j` would acquire the value that was set on the last step of the inner loop, instead of grabbing an **undefined** variable `j` to assume `0` and increment it to `1`!

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it is worth to use `time {script} n` where `n` is the number of iterations instead of a normal `while` or `for` loop. Although `time`'s purpose is not looping, the achieved effect is the same.

I made changes recently to my own answers following this direction.

**UPDATE:** I've just discovered an easy to fall pitfall: You can not replace a `for` or a `while` by a `time` block, if it contains a `break` or a `continue`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the interactive shell. This allows you to abbreviate the command names as long as only 1 command starts with the remaining letters.

Example:

- `gets` -> `ge`
- `lassign` -> `las`
- `expr` -> `exp`
- `puts` -> `pu`

And interactive solutions are free :P

**Background**:

When `tclsh` runs with a terminal as input device, it sets the variable `tcl_interactive` to `1`. This causes `unknown` (default procedure that will be called if a command can not be found) to search for commands that starts with that name.

Downside: it will print the result of every line, use `;` instead of newlines.
Ohh, and it might invoke external commands like `w`, which is a good abbreviation of `while`.

Answer (score 3):

## else is optional

As it is said on [if manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), `else` is implicit on `if` block constructs. So what is

`if ... {} else {}`

can become

`if ... {} {}`

as you can see on some of my answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Tcl 8.0.5, but I believe the following are applicable to all recent versions.

1. Use `rename` to rename `rename`:

   ```
   rename rename &
   ```

   <sup>The `&` can be any identifier; `&` just reminds me of "references" in C.</sup>
2. Use the renamed `rename` to rename `set`:

   ```
   & set =
   ```

   <sup>Again, the `=` can be any identifier; `=` is just intuitive to me.</sup>
3. Now, rename other commands that are worth renaming, *e.g.*

   ```
   & regsub R
   & string S
   & while W
   ```

   A command is worth renaming if, given its length *n*, and occurrences *k*, *k(n-1)-(n+4) > 0*. Solving for *k*, the formula becomes `k > (n+4)/(n-1)`. Here's a reference table that makes it easy:

   ```
   length of       minimum         example(s)
   command         occurrences
   ------------------------------------------------
   2               6               if (consider renaming to "?")
   3               4               for, set (consider renaming to "=")
   4               3               eval, expr, incr (consider renaming to "+"), info, join, proc, puts, scan
   5               3               break, catch, lsort, split, subst, trace, unset, while
   6               3               format, lindex, lrange, regexp, regsub, rename, return, string, switch
   7               2               foreach, lappend, linsert, llength, lsearch, unknown
   .               2               lreplace
   .               2               continue
   .               2
   ```
4. Next, compact frequently used subcommands like

   ```
   = I index
   = L length
   ```

   so you can do things like

   ```
   S $I $x 7
   S $L $x
   ```
5. Some obvious miscellanea:

   1. `lappend` can set the first element of a list if it doesn't yet exist (no need to initialize).
   2. You can set arrays without using `array`, *e.g.* `set doesNotExist(7) 43`.
   3. You can use strings (`"a b c"`) instead of `[list a b c]`.
   4. You can interpolate in strings like so: `foo${a}bar`.
   5. You can use `two\ words` rather than `"two words"`. (Remember in general that for contiguous strings without spaces, double quotes can be omitted!)
   6. You can almost always rewrite `for`s as `while`s to save a character or two, since a `while` can simultaneously check and increment while a `for` uses separate blocks.
6. For larger programs, here's a trick I thought of but haven't yet applied:

   ```
   proc unknown {c args} {eval [info commands $c*] $args}
   ```

   This emulates interactive command abbreviations! It costs 54 characters, but now you can use `j` for `join`, `sp` for `split`, `st` for `string`, `w` for `while`, and so on.

Comment: If you want to emulate interactive abbreviations, use `info script {};set tcl_interactive 1`

Comment: Cool, thanks! I've credited you [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20570/14255). There were some issues with that technique, however, that I didn't encounter with the `unknown` route: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715558/why-does-renaming-set-break-tcls-interactive-mode) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715771/why-cant-i-use-w-for-while-in-tcls-interactive-mode).

Comment: The question asks for tips which are somewhat specific to Tcl. The ternary operator is included in the [tips for all languages](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5315/194).

Answer (score 1):

May be it should be integrated on another answer, but here it goes:

When a `proc` has only one parameter it could be written as

```
proc p a {DO THINGS}
```

instead of

```
proc p {a} {DO THINGS}
```

---

The same applies to a two parameters `proc` using a backslash; it can be written as

```
proc p a\ b {DO THINGS}
```

instead of

```
proc p {a b} {DO THINGS}
```

---

For an higher number of parameters the `{}` render shorter code.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is worth to replace the two `set` statements to concatenate strings by only one `lappend` statement. On a construction like, one can substitute

```
set s ""

loop {
    # ...
    set s $s\X
}
```

by

```
loop {
    # ...
    append s X
}
```

The `append` command has an `incr` like behaviour, which initializes a not yet defined variable.

Take care to not mistake `append` by `lappend`

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling a list with an operation that syntactically is interleaving between each element, sometimes you can `join` elements to do a specific operation, instead of traversing it.

On https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127042/29325 there is an example:

```
puts \n[expr [join [split [read stdin]] +]]
```

It `read stdin` gives `23 214 52` then split will give the list `{23 214 52}`. **After, `[join {23 214 52} +]` will return the string `23+214+52`.** Finally `expr 23+214+52` does the job of summing

Comment: In this case, you can omit the `split`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have large codes, it's possible to avoid multiple usages of `expr` using `namespace pat tcl::mathop` at the beginning. It provides prefix-syntax operation as a regular Tcl fonction. For example:

```
namespace pat tcl::mathop
set sum [+ 1 2 3]
set prod [* {*}{1 2 3 4}]
puts $sum\ $prod
```

[See official mathop doc page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/mathop.htm)

Answer (score 0):

When you have several variables that are been `set` on subsequent lines you can use one `lassign` instead of several `set` instructions to achieve the same effect.

One example is my own answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105789/29325

To decide, one just needs to weight the number of variables (assuming 1 letter variables, as it is expected when golfing):

- <5, `set` is golfier
- =5, `set` and `lassign` generate the same byte count
- >5, `lassign` is golfier