# String of alphanumeric characters to a sorted list of comma-separated ranges

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string of unsorted alphanumeric characters, *e.g.*

```
ABC321STPpJqZZr0
```

output a ", "-separated list of character ranges, sorted by ASCII value, ignoring case and removing duplicates (*i.e.* outputting only uppercase and numeric characters), *e.g.*

```
0-3, A-C, J, P-T, Z
```

#### Rules

- The length of your program is your base score, as usual.
- You must initialize (hardcode) the above example within your program, but you may discount the length of that example from your program length, *e.g.* for `char* s="ABC321STPpJqZZr0";` you may discount 16 chars, the other 11 chars counting toward your program length.

#### Bonus (+50 bounty)

- As this was a real problem encountered by my coworker today, needing to be written in [Tcl 8.0.5](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TclCmd/contents.htm) (an ancient version, lacking many of the latest Tcl built-ins), I'll award 50 points to whomever writes the shortest Tcl 8.0.5 solution, if there are at least 2 valid submissions in Tcl 8.0.5.

Comment: @FezVrasta - I intentionally wrote `", "` to include the space, but we can leave your edit and let this comment serve as that indication.

Comment: Why intentionally include GolfScript? Why not allow other languages, such as Befunge?

Comment: We can say all is fair game. I just won't be able to check most of them very easily.

Comment: So is that a Code-Golf tag then?

Comment: @Chron - Good catch. A-B in my case but since there have already been many submissions, let's allow both ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Ruby, 87-16=71

**EDIT:**  Had to add some characters so that two-character ranges are displayed correctly.  Also using `?[` instead of `?Z` to fix a bug with ranges ending in Z.

```ruby
$><<[*?0..?[].join.gsub(/[^ABC321STPpJqZZr0]/i,$/).gsub(/\B.+\B/,?-).scan(/.-.|./)*', '
```

You can see the Ideone run [here](http://ideone.com/LqzhhN).

Comment: +1 For one-liner. Very clever use of various methods; This is really brilliant.

Comment: Note that `gsub(/[]/i)` is shorter than `tr(''.upcase)` by 2 characters. Moreover, `scan(/.+/)` -> `split` saves 5, and `$><<` instead of `puts` another one.

Comment: @Howard Great suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 131

```
julia> l=sort(unique(uppercase("ABC321STPpJqZZr0")))
julia> prod([!(c+1 in l)?"$c"*(c==l[end]?"":", "):!(c-1 in l)?"$c":(c+1 in l)&&!(c+2 in l)?"-":"" for c in l])

"0-3, A-C, J, P-T, Z"
```

Not supported by Ideone.com, and will probably be crushed anyway.

Comment: Thanks anyway! The Ideone.com constraint was only so I could test it but I suppose I can trust the integrity of golfers and remove that rule. +1, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript <del>57</del> <del>54</del>  52

```
 'ABC321STPpJqZZr0'
 {.95>32*-}%.|:x..{(}%&-x..{)}%&-+$2/{.|'-'*}%', '*
```

Try it [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=J0FCQzMyMVNUUHBKcVpacjAnCnsuOTU%2BMzIqLX0lLnw6eC4ueyl9JSYteC4ueyh9JSYtKyQyL3sufCctJyp9JScsICcq).

The code first capitalizes everything:

```
{.95>32*-}%
```

Then gets unique characters and saves it in a variable:

```
.|:x
```

Then, we get the characters whose direct predecessors are not in the string (so that they are the beginning part of a range):

```
..{)}%&-x
```

We similarly get the ends of ranges with `x..{)}%&-`.

Now actually form the ranges by concatenating the lists, sorting, and splitting into groups of 2:

```
+$2/
```

The rest is just formatting, using `*` as string join.

Comment: In the output, the ranges need to be separated by ', ' and not just ','

Comment: Also `.95>{32-}{}if` -> `.95>32*-` saves 5 characters.

Comment: @Howard Great!  I knew that part was suboptimal.

Comment: @Chron Fixed the space issue!

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 221 bytes

```
class P{
    static void Main(){
        var s="ABC321STPpJqZZr0";
        var l=new int[257];
        foreach(int c in s.ToUpper())
            l[c]=1;
        var r="";
        for(int i=0;i<255;){
            if(l[i++]-l[i]<0)
                r+=", "+(char)i;
            else if(l[i+1]-l[i]<0)
                r+="-"+(char)i;
        }
        System.Console.Write(r.Substring(2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 193

```
char*s="ABC321STPpJqZZr0";
int c[99];memset(c,0,396);while(*s){++c[toupper(*s++)];}for(int i=0,f=1,r=0;
i<=99;++i){if(!r&&c[i])r=i;if(r&&!c[i]){if(!f)printf(", ");putchar(r);
if(i-r>1)printf("-%c",i-1);r=f=0;}}
```

Comment: Can you add a small explanation?

Comment: Iterate over the string, accumulating a count of instances of each alphanumeric character. Then, iterate over all alphanumeric characters in alphabetical order, writing out the start of each compact range and, if appropriate, a dash followed by the end of the range. If this is not the first range that's been written, add the comma-space separator. Code must be embedded in a main() function with appropriate headers (stdio, string, ctypes) included, so I kinda cheated there.

Answer (score 2):

## Q, 94

```
{","sv(,/){{"-"sv(?) -1 1#\:x}'[cut[;a]0,1_(&)1<(-':)"i"$'a:asc upper[x]inter y]}[x]'[.Q`n`A]}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.x, 304 - 16 = 288

This can surely be golfed further, all comments welcome!

```
e=[""]*11;f=[""]*27
for c in"ABC321STPpJqZZr0".lower():e["0123456789".find(c)]=f["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".find(c)]=c
e[-1]=f[-1]=""
def h(j):
 g=[];k=l=i=0
 for e in j:
  if e:
   if not l:k=i;l=1
  elif l:l=g.append((k,i-1))
  i+=1
 print", ".join([j[m],j[m]+"-"+j[n]][n-m>1]for m,n in g)
h(e);h(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol (218 - 16 = 202)

```
m: s: sort uppercase unique"ABC321STPpJqZZr0"i: :to-integer f: does[either 1 = length? x: copy/part m s[x][rejoin[x/1"-"last x]]]while[not tail? s: next s][if(1 + i pick back s 1)!=(i s/1)[prin join f", "m: s]]print f
```

Non-minified version:

```
m: s: sort uppercase unique "ABC321STPpJqZZr0"
i: :to-integer

f: does [
    either 1 = length? x: copy/part m s [x] [rejoin [x/1 "-" last x]]
]

while [not tail? s: next s][
    if (1 + i pick back s 1) != (i s/1) [
        prin join f ", "
        m: s
    ]
]

print f
```

Answer (score 1):

## q [116 chars]

```
{.a:();{m:6h$x;.a:.a,$[m[1]=1+m[0];45;m[0],44,m 1];1_x}/[x:asc distinct upper x];p where differ 6h$p:-3_10h$x[0],.a}
```

### Usage

```
{.a:();{m:6h$x;.a:.a,$[m[1]=1+m[0];45;m[0],44,m 1];1_x}/[x:asc distinct upper x];p where differ 6h$p:-3_10h$x[0],.a}"ABC321STPpJqZZr0"
```

Output

```
"0-3,A-C,J,P-T,Z"
```

There is a scope of saving chars, i'll try some other method and post it.

Answer (score 0):

### Tcl 8.0.5, 344 (360 bytes)

```
set a ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
set s string
set x [join [lsort [split [$s toupper ABC321STPpJqZZr0] ""]] ""]
regsub -all (.)\\1+ $x \\1 x
set i 36
while {[incr i -1]} {set j -1
while {$i+[incr j]<36} {set y [$s range $a $j [expr $i+$j]]
regsub $y $x [$s index $y 0]-[$s index $y end],\  x}}
while {[regsub -all {(\w)(\w)} $x {\1, \2} x]} {}
puts $x
```

### Tcl 8.0.5, 340 (356 bytes)

Tinkering with the `rename` command yielded some fun tricks! I've documented them [in another thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20574/14255).

```
rename rename &
& set =
& regsub R
& string S
& while W
= a ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
= x [lsort [split [S toupper ABC321STPpJqZZr0] ""]]
R -all {(.) \1+| } $x \\1 x
= i 36
W {[incr i -1]} {= j -1
W {$i+[incr j]<36} {= y [S range $a $j [expr $i+$j]]
R $y $x [S index $y 0]-[S index $y end],\  x}}
W {[R -all {(\w)(\w)} $x {\1, \2} x]} {}
puts $x
```

### Tcl 8.0.5, 332 (348 bytes) [Unstable—depends on $PATH]

```
info script ""
set tcl_interactive 1
set a ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
set x [lso [sp [st toupper ABC321STPpJqZZr0] ""]]
regs -all {(.) \1+| } $x \\1 x
set i 36
wh {[inc i -1]} {set j -1
wh {$i+[inc j]<36} {set y [st range $a $j [exp $i+$j]]
regs $y $x [st index $y 0]-[st index $y end],\  x}}
wh {[regs {(\w)(\w)} $x {\1, \2} x]} {}
pu $x
```

Credit to [@JohannesKuhn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11552/tips-for-golfing-in-tcl/20574?noredirect=1#comment41501_20574) for [the interactive trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/13053/14255).

Comment: Sometimes you can save bytes replacing `while` by `time` constructs. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126236/29325