# Condense these page numbers!

Tags: code-golf, string, number

Disclaimer: while I have been on this site for entertainment purposes for a little while now, this is my first question, so please forgive any minor errors.

## Background

When assigning us homework, my teacher is really annoying and writes out *all* the problems we have to do individually. As such, it takes me *forever* to copy down which problems I have to do. I thought to make my life easier, I would send him a program that could make the list of problems take up less space.

While writing down a list of page or problem numbers, we use a dash to denote a range. For example, `19-21` becomes `19, 20, 21`. If there is a gap in between, two comma-separated ranges are used: `19-21, 27-31` becomes `19, 20, 21, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31`. 
Right about now, you're probably thinking: "this seems pretty trivial". In fact, this has already been answered [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52321/determine-ranges-from-a-list-of-values) and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20545/string-of-alphanumeric-characters-to-a-sorted-list-of-comma-separated-ranges).

However, there is a catch. If we have a range with equal consecutive digits, the repeated digits can be left out. For example: `15, 16, 17` becomes `15-7`, and `107, 108, 109` becomes `107-9`. For a bonus, if the last consecutive equal digit is 1 greater and the upper limit's last digit is less than or equal to that of the lower, the following can be omitted (sorry if that sounded confusing; perhaps some examples will clear it up). `109-113` becomes `109-3`, as a lower last digit implies increasing the 10s place.

## Challenge

Your program should take a list of integers via input (whatever is standard for your language, or a function).  You can decide whether this list is comma-separated, space-separated, or as an actual list/array.

Output the **shortest way** (first sorted by number of ranges, then the sum of the characters included in the ranges) to represent that list using this notation. Each dashed range must be on the same line, but the ranges can be separated by commas or newlines (trailing newlines or commas are allowed). These ranges must be in order.

Since our school Wi-Fi is **terrible**, I have to make the file as small as possible in order to send it to him. The shortest code (in bytes) wins.

## Bonuses

My teacher is sloppy, so there are a few things that would help him out. 
Multiple bonuses stack through multiplication, e.g. a -10% bonus (x 90%) and a -25% (x 75%) bonus = 90% * 75% = x 67.5% (-32.5% bonus).

- Sometimes he puts them in the wrong order (he's not a math teacher). Take a -20% bonus if your program can accept integers that are not sorted least-to-greatest.
- Our book is weird, and each section starts counting the problems at -10. If your program can accept negative numbers, take a -25%.
- If it accepts the bonus of a lower last digit increasing 10's place, e.g. `25-32` reducing to `25-2`, take a -50% bonus.

## Test Cases

```
In:  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Out: 1-5

In:  3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12
Out: 3-5, 9-12

In:  149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160
Out: 149-60

In: 1 2 3 4
Out: 1-4


For bonuses:

In: 109, 110, 111, 112, 113
Out: 109-3

In:  19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
Out: 19-9

In: -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2
Out: -3-2

In: -3, -2, -1
Out: -3--1
```

An answer will be accepted on Saturday, 19 December 2015.

GLHF!

Comment: Why is the output in the third test case not `1-4 9-2`?

Comment: What should be output for a program that (a) does and (b) does not take the 50% bonus, for `149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 178 159 160`?

Comment: @ThomasKwa whichever results in the least ranges, so `149-60`

Comment: The second result, `10-9`, makes no sense to me. Shouldn't it be simply `10, 19`?

Comment: How should negative numbers be represented? -5--3?

Comment: @Mego Since there will always be a `-` or space between numbers, there should be no ambiguity, so having a dash and negation sign next to each other is fine.

Comment: I could've sworn there's another question just like this, but I can't find it...

Comment: I should hope not... I spent 15 minutes looking for one. If there is one, I think it's safe to say that the question is long dead.

Comment: I feel like this same question keeps getting asked. What's going on?

Comment: I think [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51189) is the related question everybody is thinking of. That one turns ranges into lists though.

Comment: Are functions allowed?

Comment: @TheCoffeeCup that's fine.

Comment: Also, the last in/out doesn't make sense. Do you mean `In: 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29`?

Comment: Can I request the list be input one element at a time `12<enter>13<enter>14...` and terminated by a character?

Comment: @TheCoffeeCup fixed. I should have programmatically generated these.

Comment: @sysreq that's fine, I'm not particularly picky about the format of the input (anymore).

Comment: The first 'bonus' example has nothing to do with the bonuses

Comment: Can we get a clarification on whether duplicates and single pages should be handled, since none are now included in test cases?

Comment: Another thing - the text says that the penultimate digit for the ending page of the range should be cut if it's _lower_ than that of the start page, but the test case says `19-9` for `19,20,...,29` and not `19-29` as the text implies. So which is correct?

Comment: Can we get a lot more test cases... the test cases don't even cover all the bonuses. I think this would clarify a lot.

Comment: In the last paragraph of section Background, at one point the last digit is asked to be "less than or equal". Still, two questions for OP:

If indeed the last digit being not only lower but also possibly equal implies the previous digit increasing, don't `19` and `19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29` both produce `19-9`?

Sometimes you seem to want to generalize to higher carries than 10, f.x. `99,100,101,102` ^= `99-2`. Is this to be respected for the bonus?

Comment: I think `19` shall become `19` and `19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29` `19-9`. I also generalized that behaviour to any carry so that the number of digits printed depends only on the difference of start and end value: `0 -> ""`,  `1-10 -> 1 digit`, `11-100 -> 2 digits`, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## LabVIEW, 97*0.8*0.75*0.5 = 29.1 [LabVIEW Primitives](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

this works by counting upwards if sucessive elemts are 1 apart and then creates a string from the the number and the number - count modulo 10 and some multiplication cause negatives are a bitch.

The gif showcases an input of `8,9,10,11` and outputs `8-1`. For input `-5,-4,-3,1,3,4,5` `-5--3,1,3-5`comes out.

[image]

Comment: Really, counting it as each for loop/while loop/if/whatever is 1 primitive isn't fair because in languages like JS, they count as more than 1 byte...

Comment: @ev3commander anything's fair if it comes with a cool animated diagram!

Comment: thats why its in primitives not bytes. Also theres a lot of wiring going on so the loops actaully are 2 or 3 at least and also another 3 per shift register + initialisation.

Comment: @cyoce Noooooope. I could create a new language called "CondPgNmbrs" and add some diagram of how the language works, and that would be "fair"...

Comment: by standard golf rules you can do that, its just boring

Comment: @ev3commander Actually, if the language is newer than the challenge you are not allowed to use it for competitive reasons.

Comment: @Adnan actually at least most of the time newer languages are allowed

Comment: @Eumel Even for competitive reasons? Can you give an example?

Comment: ok most of the time might have been a slight exxageration, but every once in a while i stumble upon a set of rules that allows newer languages and i always regarded those as the standard rules.

Comment: @Adnan I know, that's my point. not "anything's fair with a cool animated diagram"...

Answer (score 13):

### C++11, 451 * 80% * 75% * 50% = 135.3 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to @kirbyfan64sos.

Saved 19 bytes thanks to @JosephMalle and @cat.

Saved 11 bytes thanks to @pinkfloydx33.

```
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#define T string
#define P append
using namespace std;T f(vector<int>v){sort(v.begin(),v.end());T r=to_T(v[0]);int b=1;int m=v[0];for(int i=1;i<=v.size();i++){if(i!=v.size()&&v[i]==v[i-1]+1){if(!b){m=v[i-1];}b=1;}else{if(b){T s=to_T(v[i-1]);r.P("-").P(s.substr(s.size()-(v[i-1]-m==1?1:log10(v[i-1]-m)),s.size()));}if(i!=v.size()){r.P(", ").P(to_T(v[i]));}b=0;}}return r;}
```

This qualifies for all the bonuses.

Sample parameter test and result:

```
In:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Out: 1-5

In:  [3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12]
Out: 3-5, 9-12

In:  [149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160]
Out: 149-60

In:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
Out: 1-4

In:  [109, 110, 111, 112, 113]
Out: 109-3

In:  [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
Out: 19-9
```

Comment: Why not use `int` instead of `unsigned int`? Saves 9 bytes.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Thanks, didn't notice that.

Comment: +1 always like to see C++. I can't test this, but I don't think you need iostream

Comment: I don't think you need iostream either, but `gcc` gave: `a.cpp: In function ‘std::string f(std::vector<int>)’:
a.cpp:8:83: error: ‘to_string’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @cat Make sure it's updated enough that it supports the C++11 standard. 4.3-ish should be good with `-std=c++11`; >= 5.0 has it on by default (actually it's `-std=gnu11`, but close enough).

Comment: @Mego All `-std=c++11` does is give me multiple screenfuls of errors and gcc saying `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. This is gcc 4.8.4 on Linux. (Not that it matters that it won't compile for me)

Comment: @cat That would be because this is a function, not a full program. Add something like `int main(){cout<<f({1,2,3,4,5})<<endl;return 0;}` to the code and it'll be a full program. With that addition, it compiles and runs fine under gcc 5.2.0 on Linux.

Comment: @Mego Oh, duh. I don't know C++ but I saw the `using` and the includes and assumed a instantly compilable answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this give `unsigned-signed mismatch`? If it does, use C++11 or above and `auto` instead of `int`

Comment: @ev3commander yes, but it's a warning, and it seems to run fine with the warning. The question didn't state that it had to be warning-free.

Comment: @TheCoffeeCup  just tried compiling in vs, it works

Comment: you can save 13 bytes using `int b;` swapping the if statements `if(b)` => `if(!b)` (and vise-versa), replacing the `b=true` with `b=0` and the `b=false` with `b=1`

Comment: why not claim the two extra from `int b;` (no =1) and inverting the rest? compiles with warning, sure... but it works

Answer (score 8):

### Ruby, <s>120</s> 118 * 0.8 * 0.75 * 0.5 = 35.4 bytes

Takes command-line arguments as input (commas are okay); prints one range per line to standard output.

```ruby
c=(b=(a=$*.map(&:to_i).sort).map &:succ)-a
puts (a-b).map{|m|(m<n=c.shift-1)?"#{m}-#{m<0?n:n%10**"#{n-m-1}".size}":m}
```

With whitespace/comments:

```ruby
c=(
  b=(
    # a is the sorted input
    a=$*.map(&:to_i).sort
  # b is the set of successors of elements of a
  ).map &:succ
# c=b-a is the set of not-quite-least upper bounds of our ranges
)-a

# a-b is the set of greatest lower bounds of our ranges
puts (a-b).map {|m|
  # for each range [m,n], if there are multiple elements
  (m < n = c.shift-1) ?
    # yield the range, abbreviating n appropriately if positive
    "#{m}-#{m<0 ? n : n % 10 ** "#{n-m-1}".size}" :
    # in the one-element case, just yield that
    m
}
```

**Test cases**

```ruby
$ ruby homework.rb 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1-5

$ ruby homework.rb 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12
3-5
9-2

$ ruby homework.rb 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160
149-60

$ ruby homework.rb 1 2 3 4
1-4

$ ruby homework.rb 109, 110, 111, 112, 113
109-3

$ ruby homework.rb 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
19-9
```

**Features not covered by test cases**

Unordered input & single-element ranges:

```ruby
$ ruby homework.rb 2 17 19 22 0 1 8 20 18
0-2
8
17-0
22
```

Negative ranges (not possible to abbreviate the larger number with these):

```ruby
$ ruby homework.rb -17 -18 -19 -20 -21
-21--17
```

Abbreviation of arbitrary numbers of digits (ordinary bash expansion used for the input here):

```ruby
$ ruby homework.rb {1234567..1235467} 2345999 2346000 2346001
1234567-467
2345999-1
```

Comment: I believe you can replace `((n=c.shift-1)>m)` with `m<n=c.shift-1`

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript ES6, 229 * 80% * 75% * 50% = 68.7 bytes

### Test Input

I'm using the following test data:

```
var A1=[
  5,6,7,            // => 5-7     # (a) group pages 
  2,3,              // => 2-3,5-7 # (b) must be properly sorted
  -9,-8,-7,         // => -10--8  # (c) allow negative numbers
  29,30,31,32,      // => 29-2    # (d) lower last digit implies increasing the 10s place
  9,10,11,12,       // => 9-11    # NOT 9-2
  36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47, 
                    // => 36-47   # NOT 36-7
  99,100,101,102,   // => 99-102  # NOT 99-2
  109,110,111,112,  // => 109-2   # NOT 109-12
],
// more tests, not specified in the question
A2=[
  120,124,       // => 120,124 # (e) handle single pages
],
A3=[
  135,136,135    // => 135-6   # (f) handle duplicates
];
```

### Basic: 229 bytes

This version satisfies the requirements of the question (a) with all bonuses (c,d,e), but hangs on single pages. It can also handle duplicates(f). It handles negative pages down to -10,000, which can be easily increased with (large) loss of speed.

```
F=(a)=>{var R=[],i=NaN,l,u;a.map(x=>R[1e4+x]=x);R.concat('').map(x=>(i!=i&&(l=x,u=l-1),i=0,u=(x+="")-u-1?l=console.log(l+'-'+(u>0?(l.length-u.length||(z=>{for(;l[i]==u[i];i++);})(),u.length-i-2||u-l>9||i++,u.slice(i)):u))||x:x))}
F(A1.concat(A3)) --> -9--7 2-3 5-7 9-12 29-2 36-47 99-102 109-2 135-136
```

(The output above shows spaces instead of actual newlines for brevity)

### Single pages: 233 bytes

This slightly longer version additionally satisfies (e) and displays single pages as a range with equal lower and upper limits

```
G=(a)=>{var R=[],i=NaN,l,u;a.map(x=>R[1e4+x]=x);R.concat('').map(x=>(i!=i&&(l=x,u=l-1),i=0,u=(x+="")-u-1?l=console.log(l+'-'+(u-l&u>0?(l.length-u.length||(z=>{for(;l[i]==u[i];i++);})(),u.length-i-2||u-l>9||i++,u.slice(i)):u))||x:x))}
G(A1.concat(A2,A3)) --> -9--7 2-3 5-7 9-12 29-2 36-47 99-102 109-2 120-120 124-124
```

Comment: @Cyoce - Are you using an ES6-enabled javascript engine?

Comment: Oh, hmm, I have a bug, it doesn't actually handle 36-47 correctly. What's the proper procedure? Do I delete it and fix it, or just try to fix it (I may not have the time right now), or what?

Comment: Hmm, it just works in my Chrome. What gives?

Comment: And zocky, fix it when you can. It just won't count as valid until it's fixed, and as such can not be accepted until then (assuming yours is the fewest bytes).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32984/discussion-between-cyoce-and-zocky).

Comment: Nice, it works!

Comment: Why `99-102  # NOT 99-2` ?

Comment: ... and I think the single page should be managed, even if it's not in the test cases. The test cases or not meant to cover all possible cases.

Comment: Test `[-3,-2,-1]` fails

Comment: The longer version should manage single pages but fails on `[1,3]` (testing with FireFox) BUT works in Chrome

Comment: @edc: _Why 99-102 # NOT 99-2_  - I was extrapolating from 9-12, as included in the question.

Comment: OK, I now have a new version, and the one with bells and whistles is now significantly shorter. It now works for me on `G([1,3])` in FireFox, but it still  ignores any ranges that end in -1. I'm at a loss there, for now.

Comment: I don't think the parentheses in `F=(a)=>` are required. Also, `var` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @zocky 9-12 was if you're not going for the bonuses. Since you are, it should be 99-2

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, 322*80%*75%*50% = 96.6 Bytes

Finally done with the 3 challenges, Scores under 100 bytes :D

#### Golfed

```lua
function f(l)table.sort(l)l[#l+1]=-13 a=l[1]t,s=a,"" for _,v in next,l do if v-t>1 or t-v>1 then s,p,r=s..a.."-",""..t,""..a r:gsub("%d",function(c)p=r:find(c)~=r:len()and p:gsub("^(-?)"..c,"%1")or p r=r:gsub("^"..c,"")end)p=t-a<10 and t%10<a%10 and p:gsub("^(%d)","")or p s,a,t=s..p..",",v,v else t=v end end return s end
```

#### Ungolfed

```lua
function f(l)
    table.sort(l)
    l[#l+1]=-13 
    a=l[1] 
    t,s=a,"" 
    for _,v in next,l 
    do
        if v-t>1 or t-v>1
        then
            s,p,r=s..a.."-",""..t,""..a
            r:gsub("%d",function(c)
                p=r:find(c)~=#r and p:gsub("^(-?)"..c,"%1")or p
                r=r:gsub("^"..c,"")
            end)
            p=t-a<10 and t%10<a%10 and p:gsub("^(%d)","")or p
            s=s..p..","
            a,t=v,v
        else
            t=v
        end
    end
return s
end
```

You can test lua [online](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo), to see how it perform against the test cases, copy paste the function, followed by this code :

```lua
a={1,2,3,4,5}
b={3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}
c={149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160}
d={-7,8,5,-6,-5,6,7}
print(f(a))
print(f(b))
print(f(c))
print(f(d))
```

Comment: Seems to fail if {9..21} is entered. Outputs 9-1.

Comment: @ICanHazHats Fixed, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 3):

## [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org), 355 Bytes *0.8*0.75*0.5 = 106.5

This satisfies all the bonuses. It cost me almost 100 extra bytes to make everything work nicely. This function only omits leading digits if the gap does not overflow the ones place once. For example `9 10 11` outputs `9-1` but `9 10 11 12 .. 20 21` outputs `9-21`.

If GAP was a little less verbose, I could have gotten this pretty short (also could have saved many bytes if I didn't follow the exact syntax.) I'll probably try golfing this a bit harder tomorrow. See below for test cases.

```
g:=function(l)local n;if not l=[] then Sort(l);n:=1;while not l=[] do;if not IsSubset(l,[l[1]..l[1]+n]) then if not n=1 then if n-1>10-l[1] mod 10 and n-1<11 then Print(l[1],"-",(l[1]+n-1) mod 10);else Print(l[1],"-",l[1]+n-1);fi;else Print(l[1]);fi;Print(", ");SubtractSet(l,[l[1]..l[1]+n-1]);g(l);fi;n:=n+1;od;fi;Print("\b\b  ");end;
```

ungolfed:

```
g:=function(l)
    local n;
    if not l=[] then
        Sort(l);
        n:=1;
        while not l=[] do;
            if not IsSubset(l,[l[1]..l[1]+n]) then
                if not n=1 then
                    if n-1>10-l[1] mod 10 and n-1<11 then
                        Print(l[1],"-",(l[1]+n-1) mod 10);
                    else
                        Print(l[1],"-",l[1]+n-1);
                    fi;
                else
                    Print(l[1]);
                fi;
                Print(", ");
                SubtractSet(l,[l[1]..l[1]+n-1]);
                g(l);
            fi;
            n:=n+1;
        od; 
    fi;
    Print("\b\b  ");
end;
```

Note that in GAP syntax, `[a..b]` is equivalent to `[a,a+1,...,b]`. I believe that these test cases demonstrate that this program meets all the requirements. If something is wrong, let me know.

```
gap> h([1..5]);
1-5  
gap> h([3,4,5,9,10,11,12]);
3-5, 9-2  
gap> h([149..160]);
149-160  
gap> h([109..113]);
109-3  
gap> h([19..29]);
19-9  

gap> h([-1,-2,-3,-7,-20000,9,10,110101,110102]);
-20000, -7, -3--1, 9-10, 110101-110102  

gap> h([10101,10102,10103,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,234,999,1000,1001,1002]);
10-16, 234, 999-2, 10101-10103
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 252 * 80% * 75% * 50% = 75.6 bytes

I've decided to go for a method (is much smaller in Java), here is the golfed version:

#### Golfed

```java
int p,c,s;String m(int[]a){p=s=c=0;c--;String o="";Arrays.sort(a);for(int n:a){if(s==0)o+=s=n;else if(n-p==1)c++;else{o+=t()+", "+(s=n);c=-1;}p=n;}return o+t();}String t(){return c>=0?"-"+(""+p).substring((""+Math.abs(p)).length()-(""+c).length()):"";}
```

And here is the readable version:

```java
int p, c, s;

String m(int[] a) {
    p = s = c = 0;
    c--;
    String o = "";
    Arrays.sort(a);
    for (int n : a) {
        if (s == 0)
            o += s = n;
        else if (n - p == 1)
            c++;
        else {
            o += t() + ", " + (s = n);
            c = -1;
        }
        p = n;
    }
    return o + t();
}

String t() {
    return c >= 0 ? "-" + ("" + p).substring(("" + Math.abs(p)).length() - ("" + c).length()) : "";
}
```

When tested these are the results:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class A {
    public static void main(String...s) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.m(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
        System.out.println(a.m(new int[] {3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12}));
        System.out.println(a.m(new int[] {149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160}));
        System.out.println(a.m(new int[] {109, 110, 111, 112, 113}));
        System.out.println(a.m(new int[] {19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}));
        System.out.println(a.m(new int[] {1,10,11,16}));
        System.out.println(a.m(new int[] {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}));
        System.out.println(a.m(new int[] {-3,-2,-1}));
    }

    int p,c,s;String m(int[]a){p=s=c=0;c--;String o="";Arrays.sort(a);for(int n:a){if(s==0)o+=s=n;else if(n-p==1)c++;else{o+=t()+", "+(s=n);c=-1;}p=n;}return o+t();}String t(){return c>=0?"-"+(""+p).substring((""+Math.abs(p)).length()-(""+c).length()):"";}
}
```

Output:

```
1-5
3-5, 9-2
149-60
109-3
19-9
1, 10-1, 16
-3-3
-3--1
```

#### Update:

It can now handle negative numbers as well, adding to the bonus.

Comment: I'm no Java expert, but could you shorten it by changing `p=s=c=0;c--;` to `p=s=0;c=-1;` ?

Comment: I'm no Java expert, but could you shorten it by changing return c >= 0 ? "bla" : "" to return c < 0 ? "": "bla" ?

Comment: you could even do `c=~(p=s=0)` for style points.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 127 bytes * 80% * 75% * 50% = 38.1

Wow, that was one heck of a challenge to include all the bonuses. It could probably be made shorter.

```
D=[]N=Nn-;DpNr@Y-1¥Xg1 ?[Xg Y]:DpX ©[YY]}D;Ds1 £[BC]=Xms;B¥C?B:B+'-+CsBg ¦'-©Cl ¥Bl ©C¬r@B¯Z ¥C¯Z ªC-B§ApCl -Z ©ÂBsX <ÂCsX ?Z:X
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=RD1bXU49Tm4tO0RwTnJAWS0xpVhnMSA/W1hnIFldOkRwWCCpW1lZXX1EO0RzMSCjW0JDXT1YbXM7QqVDP0I6QisnLStDc0OsckBCr1ogpUOvWiCqQy1Cp0FwQ2wgLVogqcJCc1ggPMJDc1ggP1o6WA==&input=MTAwOCwxMDA5LDEwMTAsMTAxMSwxMDEyLDEwMTMsMTAxNCwxMDE1LDEwMTYsMTAxNywxMDE4LDEwMTksMTAyOSwxMDMw)

#### How it works

The explanation is very rough; don't hesitate to ask any questions you might have.

```
/*    Setting up basic variables    */
                      // Implicit: A = 10, N = list of input numbers.
D=[],N=Nn-;           // D = empty array, N = N sorted by subtraction.

/*    Finding ranges of page numbers    */    
Dp                    // Push into D the result of
NrXYZ{                // reducing each previous value X and item Y in N by this function,
}[];                  // starting with an empty array:
 Y-1==Xg1 ?           //  If Y is 1 more than the second item of X,
 [Xg Y]:              //   return [X[0], Y].
 DpX &&[YY]           //  Otherwise, push X into D and return [Y, Y].

/*    Formatting result    */
Ds1 mXYZ{             // Take the first item off of D and map each item X by this function:
 [BC]=Xms;            //  Set B and C to the first to items in X as strings.
 B==C?B               //  If B is the same as C, return B.
 :B+'-+Cs             //  Otherwise, return B + a hyphen + C.slice(
  Bg !='-&&           //   If B[0] is not a hyphen (B is not negative), AND
  Cl ==Bl &&          //   B and C are the same length,

  /*    Cutting off unnecessary digits    */
  Cq r                //    then C split into digits, reduced with
  rXYZ{               //    each previous value X, item Y, and index Z mapped by this function:
   Bs0,Z ==Cs0,Z ||   //     If B.slice(0,Z) equals C.slice(0,Z), OR
   C-B<=ApCl -Z       //     C - B <= 10 to the power of (C.length - Z);
   &&~~BsX <~~CsX     //     AND B.slice(X) is a smaller number than C.slice(X),
   ?Z:X               //     then Z; otherwise, X.
                      //   Otherwise, 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 167 bytes x 80% x 75% x 50% -> 50.1

```
s=sort(scan(se=","));r=c();while(length(s)){w=s==1:length(s)+s[1]-1;x=s[w];s=s[!w];z=tail(x,1);r=c(r,paste0(x[1],"-",ifelse(z-x[1]<=10,z%%10,z%%100)))};cat(r,sep=", ")
```

Indented, with new lines:

```r
s=sort(scan(se=","))
r=c()
while(length(s)){
w=s==1:length(s)+s[1]-1
x=s[w]
s=s[!w]
z=tail(x,1)
r=c(r, paste0(x[1],"-", ifelse(z-x[1]<=10, 
                               z%%10,
                               z%%100)))}
cat(r,sep=", ")
```

Test cases:

```
> s=sort(scan(se=","));r=c();while(length(s)){w=s==1:length(s)+s[1]-1;x=s[w];s=s[!w];r=c(r,paste0(x[1],"-",ifelse(tail(x,1)-x[1]<=10,tail(x,1)%%10,tail(x,1)%%100)))};cat(r,sep=", ")
1: 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12
8: 
Read 7 items
3-5, 9-2
> s=sort(scan(se=","));r=c();while(length(s)){w=s==1:length(s)+s[1]-1;x=s[w];s=s[!w];r=c(r,paste0(x[1],"-",ifelse(tail(x,1)-x[1]<=10,tail(x,1)%%10,tail(x,1)%%100)))};cat(r,sep=", ")
1: 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160
13: 
Read 12 items
149-60
```

It works for the -50% bonus:

```
> s=sort(scan(se=","));r=c();while(length(s)){w=s==1:length(s)+s[1]-1;x=s[w];s=s[!w];r=c(r,paste0(x[1],"-",ifelse(tail(x,1)-x[1]<=10,tail(x,1)%%10,tail(x,1)%%100)))};cat(r,sep=", ")
1: 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
12: 
Read 11 items
19-9
> s=sort(scan(se=","));r=c();while(length(s)){w=s==1:length(s)+s[1]-1;x=s[w];s=s[!w];r=c(r,paste0(x[1],"-",ifelse(tail(x,1)-x[1]<=10,tail(x,1)%%10,tail(x,1)%%100)))};cat(r,sep=", ")
1: 109, 110, 111, 112, 113
6: 
Read 5 items
109-3
```

It accepts unsorted input:

```
> s=sort(scan(se=","));r=c();while(length(s)){w=s==1:length(s)+s[1]-1;x=s[w];s=s[!w];r=c(r,paste0(x[1],"-",ifelse(tail(x,1)-x[1]<=10,tail(x,1)%%10,tail(x,1)%%100)))};cat(r,sep=", ")
1: 114, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113
7: 
Read 6 items
109-4
```

It accepts negative numbers:

```
> s=sort(scan(se=","));r=c();while(length(s)){w=s==1:length(s)+s[1]-1;x=s[w];s=s[!w];r=c(r,paste0(x[1],"-",ifelse(tail(x,1)-x[1]<=10,tail(x,1)%%10,tail(x,1)%%100)))};cat(r,sep=", ")
1: -1,0,1,2
4: 
Read 3 items
-1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

## sh, 135 * .8 * .75 * .5 = 40.5

```sh
tr , \\n|sort -n|awk -vORS="" '$1-o>1||!c{print p c$1;s=$1}{o=$1;c=", ";p=""}o>s{p="-"substr(o,length(o)-length(o-s-1)+1)}END{print p}'
```

shell script

```
tr , \\n|           # comma separated -> newline separated
sort -n|            # sort
awk -vORS=""        # suppress automatic newlines in output
```

awk script

```
# on step > 1 or first run, end the current sequence and start a new one.
# on first run, p and c are empty strings.
$1-o>1||!c
    {print p c$1;s=$1}

# old = current, c = ", " except for first run, clear end string.
    {o=$1;c=", ";p=""}

# if the sequence is not a single number, its end is denoted by "-o".
# print only the last n digits of o.
o>s
    {p="-"substr(o,length(o)-length(o-s-1)+1)}

# end the current sequence without starting a new one.
END
    {print p}'
```

where `s` is the start of the current sequence and `o` is the previous input value.

Comment: I like it, but it doesn't get the -25% bonus currently. substr() is chopping off minus signs and significant digits.

Comment: @ezrast This is actually correct behaviour in terms of the -50% bonus: `-31, -30, -29, -28` increases in the 10's place from `-3` to `-2` and shall therefore be condensed to `-31-8`. I also see the ambiguity it creates, but that's what is asked for.