# How many pages have issues?

Tags: code-golf, string

At work I've been acting as quality control on our public documents, to make sure that they are [WCAG 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) compliant. Given the length of some of these documents there tend to be issues, and so I record the issues and the pages they occur on.

## The challenge: Given a string input, output a count of all distinct pages within the string.

### Rules:

- Input will consist of of a non-empty string containing the pages, page ranges, and the issue. Multiple pages and page ranges are guaranteed to be separated by commas `,`.

```
pgs 810-812, 897, 1043, 1047, 1219, 1308, 1317, 1323 restructure reading boxes
```

```
pgs 810-812,897,1043, 1047,1219, 1308, 1317, 1323 restructure reading boxes
```

Both of the above are possible valid inputs.

- This input can be multiple lines, with each line representing a different issue.

```
pgs 810-812, 897, 1043, 1047, 1219, 1308, 1317, 1323 restructure reading boxes
pgs 816, 819, 826, 827, 829, 853, 861, 866, 885, 1043, 1142, 1143, 1164 table needs to be read as table or figure
```

You can take a multiline input as a list of strings, with each item in the list being a line. The output is still based on the entirety of the list.

- The input format is not necessarily `pgs <page numbers> <issue>`.

  Both `pg 1324 read all` and `Read all` are valid inputs.

  If the string consists of only `<Issue>`, this represents that the document is a single page, and thus the output would be `1` (no matter how many lines of input there are). If there is more than one page, you are guaranteed to not have this format as a line of the input.

### Test Cases:

```
Input:
------
pgs 810-812, 897, 1043, 1047, 1219, 1308, 1317, 1323 restructure reading boxes

Output: 
-------
10


Input:
------
pgs 587,897, 936, 939,946, 1308 single figure
pgs 810-812, 897, 1043, 1047, 1219,1308,1317, 1323 restructure reading boxes

Output:
-------
14


Input:
------
pgs 824, 873, 941-943, 1032, 1034, 1036-1040, 1055, 1071, 1153, 1154, 1228 figures as figures
pgs 1036-1040 Color Contrast for negative balance numbers does not meet WGAC 2.0 guidelines
pg 1324 read all

Output:
-------
18

Input:
------
Incorrect Reading Order

Output:
-------
1

Input:
------
Incorrect Reading Order
Pg 1 Read Table as Table
Pgs 1 Color Contrast for negative balance numbers does not meet WGAC 2.0 guidelines

Output:
-------
1
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Inverse of this?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66392/condense-these-page-numbers)

Comment: @Veskah Not really an inverse. That one condenses pages into page ranges, the inverse would take page ranges, and output a list of pages. Mine is just a count of involved pages.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8588/return-each-number-from-a-group-of-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Definitely strongly related, but I'd say the difference in input and output make it not a duplicate.

Comment: @williamporter the core of the challenge is still parsing a format like `a,b-c,d`; adding a `count unique` and removing the other characters does not, in my estimation, make it different enough, but the community is welcome to override that.

Comment: I think there’s enough here to warrant a new question. It also requires handling of numbers within the issue text. In any case here’s my 45 byte Jelly Solution written before closure: https://tio.run/##PYzNSsNAFIX3fYr7AIlkJhObEhCkoghu3Oh6aqYhcZqU/AjdNW4CutNFXSgudCmCIMEQcZHQQh8j8yJxEtDNxznn3nM8xvmibdd3vPl6FmnelJ9NkYq0EOn3drXJRPozd5i4fqsfDixpFLV6Pb7c3MgEN@Wt@Hj3xPJJkRc1XDTFS2fODk9PqhK1llg@VjmoeyBTq84G63v5UWey621XslLlVd62cycCExMFzKGuwIggdUSkQJqOe5KeuyrSiNZJw@g4RJLI0Ht2LxibMHWdJGQR0OhPDrr1/zqMAx6Ekn4c0iiGqTQ@c2jsXjGYUE79CwZ@MpuwMAI7kEt@EMOMsRjOj/bHgHc0cBLXZtz1@21AOiYQMmoD5fwX

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>51</s> 38 bytes

*-13 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen!*

```
',ð:#ʒ'-м€.ïß}D.ï≠ÅÏ'-¡¤LsнUʒX<›]˜Ùg1M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXefwBivlU5PUdS/sedS0Ru/w@sPza12A1KPOBYdbD/er6x5aeGiJT/GFvaGnJkXYPGrYFXt6zuGZ6Ya@//8rKSkVpBcrWBiZ6ChYmBvrWJoY6lqaGOsYGhgb6SgASRMwaaZraGBiAGKamoJIc0MgaWhqDCZBSoyMLBTSMtNLi1KLFRKLYUwukNlw7QrO@Tn5RUAyr6QosbhEIQ3IyUtNTyzJLEtVSErMScxLTlXIK81NSi0qVkjJB5qUl1@ikJuaWqIQ7u7orGCkZ6CQXpqZkpqTmQc2W8HQ2MhEoSg1MUUhMScH6BUA)

#### Explanation

```
                                      // Implicitly Read in multiline string 
 ',ð:#                                //Swap commas with spaces and split on spaces
      ʒ'-м€.ïß}                       //Filter list to only those with - removed are numbers
               D                      //Duplicate
                .ï≠ÅÏ                 //For all the ones that aren't numbers (so the ranges)
                    '-¡               //Split on dashes
                       ¤L             //Generate list from 1 to the highest number
                         sнU          //Stick the lower number in the variable U
 ʒ®<›]                                //Filter out numbers less than the lower number
      ˜                               //deep flatten
        Ùg                            //Uniquify and count 
          1M                          //Push 1 then output the largest number in the stack
```

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/y4uxogey). Summary of changes: input as a multi-line string, so `|»` can be removed. `' ` has a builtin: `ð`. The `{н` can be `ß` (minimum). `'-' :#` can simply be a split: `'-¡`. The `D` is unnecessary by using `¤` instead of `θ` (both get the last item, but `¤` doesn't pop, and `θ` does pop). The `©`, `®` can be `U`/`X` (or alternatively `V`/`Y`) so the `s` can be removed before the filter; these pop and store, whereas `©` stores without popping. `ï` can be removed (I think); and `D>i1` can be simplified to `1‚à` (pair with 1, and then pop+push maximum).

Comment: Thanks @KevinCruijssen I'll update when I get a chance, some excellent ideas I can use in the future in there too!

Comment: Yep, that's why I tried to explain my changes instead of just giving the 39 byter, so you can learn from it for future challenges. :) Nice answer though. That initial `',' :#` had me confused for a bit when I changed it to `',¡` like the split on `-` later on. It will leave leading spaces before the numbers, causing all kind of issues later on in the first filter.. And the `€` before the `.ï` is to also filter out the `2.0` I noticed. Nice work-around! :)

Comment: Too bad `ʒ'-мDþQ}` also leaves the empty items, which is how I usually only leave numbers. ;)

Comment: oh, one last byte to golf (for now ;p), so it becomes 38: my suggestion of `1‚à` can be `1M` (push 1, push largest number on the stack).

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5 (`-p`), 63 bytes

```
s/-/../g;s/^pgs?|[^., \d].*//g;map$h{$_}=1,eval}{$\=(keys%h)||1
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##PYzRSsMwFIbvfYpz0YFK2zRp6jpkiOzCR/DCOcnsWVeWJiFJB7Lu1Y1pYd58/Ofn/J9BK6sQHMlInpP22ZGdad3L@LHLU9g2n/kjiW0vTHK8JF/XNU3xLOT1kmzX9yf8cYvjwzjSEOIIasZTqJdlCitOsxWPgRYlm8lnPmW04MUUq2rikkbSqpw5vTBWw6FrB4sOhLvFu8n@P4eNltpGKm@F83CIh8JW@O6MsBdSqG8ENfR7tA4aHU1Ke@gRPby/vW6A5QW0Q9eg7NTsBloyDhZFA0LKX218p5ULmfkD)