# Print number triangle

Tags: code-golf, number

Given a number `N`, output a NxN right angled triangle, where each row `i` is filled with numbers up to `i`.

**Example**

**n** = 0

(no output)

**n** = 4

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

**n** = 10

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
.
.
.
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

(no alignment needed)

**n** = N

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
.
.
.
1 2 3 4 .... N
```

There is no trailing space at the end of each line.

Least number of bytes wins, and standard loopholes are not allowed.

Comment: Can the output be a nested list of numbers?

Comment: What should be the behavior for n=0, and for n>9?

Comment: @Sieg Sure, as long as the output is correct.

Comment: @freekvd for 0 there is no output, for n>9 no special formatting required

Comment: Ah darn, you broke my submission.  Fixing ASAP

Comment: Can you include an example larger than 10 we can see how two double-digit numbers should look together?

Answer (score 20):

## [Joe](https://github.com/JaniM/Joe), <strike>5</strike> 3 bytes (+2 or +3 for `-t` flag)

Well, apparently I didn't utilize the full potential of Joe. This was possible back when I first posted this.

```
\AR
```

Here, `R` gives the range from 0 to n, exclusive. Then `\A` takes successive prefixes of it (`A` is the identity function). Examples:

With `-t` flag (note: this is now the standard output even without the flag):

```
   (\AR)5
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
   \AR5
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
   \AR2
0
0 1
   \AR1
0
   \AR0
```

Without it:

```
   \AR5
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
   (\AR)5
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
   \AR2
[[0], [0, 1]]
   \AR1
[[0]]
   \AR0
[]
```

---

The rules got changed a bit. My old code didn't behave correctly with N =0. Also, now output could be just a nested list, so `-t` can be dropped.

```
1R1+R
```

Now, `Rn` gives a range from 0 to n, exclusive. If given 0, it returns an empty list.  `1+` adds 1 to every element of that range. `1R` maps the values to ranges from 1 to x. Empty liats, when mapped, return empty lists.

Example output:

```
   1R1+R0
[]
   1R1+R5
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Update: I just noticed something. The function automatically maps to rank 0 elements. The following example is run with `-t` flag.

```
   1R1+R3 5 8
1
1 2
1 2 3

1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5

1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

---

Old: 5 bytes (with the `-t` flag)

```
1R1R
```

This is an anonymous function which takes in a number, creates a list from 1 to N (`1Rn`) and maps those values to the preceding range, giving a range from 1 to x for each item of range 1 to N.

The `-t` flag gives output as a J-like table.

```
   1R1R5
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Note : the language is very new and not complete, but the latest version was released before this challenge.

Comment: So J was not enough for having an advantage on array based challenges ? :D

Comment: @Optimizer Optimizing is important.

Comment: Suddenly, my most voted answer is the one I spent the least time on. The injustice.

Comment: I guess Joe is not your average Joe...

Answer (score 10):

## Python 3, <s>48</s> 45 bytes

```py
f=lambda n:n and[f(n-1),print(*range(1,n+1))]
```

Hooray for side effects.

Comment: Nested nothingness. Now that's twisted.

Comment: That's a nifty trick: putting the function before the `print` to execute the `print`s in reverse order.

Answer (score 8):

### APL, 5

```
⍪⍳¨⍳⎕
```

creates a vector 1..n and for each element another such vector.

Then ⍪ makes a column out of all vectors. This avoids the problem with trailing blanks.

Try it on [tryapl.org](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u236A%u2373%A8%u23734&run)

---

Older solution:

```
{⎕←⍳⍵}¨⍳⎕
```

Creates a vector 1..n

{⎕←⍳⍵} is a function that outputs for each (¨) element a vector 1..n on a separate line

This one can't be tried on tryapl.org unfortunately, because ⎕← doesn't work there.

Comment: There should be no trailing spaces in any line.

Comment: ah thank you, i missed that one. Will correct soon

Comment: I knew APL would be a solution

Comment: Oh God, what are my eyes seeing

Answer (score 6):

## J, 27 bytes

J is not good with non-array numeric output. This function creates a properly formatted string from the numbers.

```
   ;@(<@,&LF@":@:>:@:i.@>:@i.)

   (;@(<@,&LF@":@:>:@:i.@>:@i.)) 4
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

[Try it online here.](http://tryj.tk/)

Comment: You could also use `]\@i.` to get `;@(<@,&LF@":@:>:@:]\@i.)`

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 53 Bytes

Edit 2: [Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47657/print-number-triangle/47688#comment112221_47688) suggested reading from input instead of defining a function, so the score is now 53 bytes for PHP:

```php
for($a=1;@$i++<$n=$argv[1];$a.=" ".($i+print"$a\n"));
```

And once again, it can be improved if PHP is configured to ignore errors (52 bytes):

```php
for($a=1;$i++<$n=$argv[1];$a.=" ".($i+print"$a\n"));
for($a=1;$i++<$n=$_GET[n];$a.=" ".($i+print"$a\n"));
```

---

Edit: [Austin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47657/print-number-triangle/47688#comment112085_47688) suggested a 60 bytes version in the comments:

```php
function f($n){for($a=1;@$i++<$n;$a.=" ".($i+print"$a\n"));}
```

Which can be improved if we doesn't display PHP errors (59 bytes):

```php
function f($n){for($a=1;$i++<$n;$a.=" ".($i+print"$a\n"));}
```

`$a` stores the next line that will be printed, and each time it's printed a space and the next number ([`print`](http://php.net/print) always returns `1`) are concatened to it.

---

Recursive functions (65 bytes):

```php
function f($n){$n>1&&f($n-1);echo implode(' ',range(1,$n))."\n";}
function f($n){$n>1&&f($n-1);for(;@$i++<$n;)echo$i,' ';echo"\n";}   // Using @ to hide notices.
```

Shorter recursive function, with error reporting disabled (64 bytes):

```php
function f($n){$n>1&&f($n-1);for(;$i++<$n;)echo$i,' ';echo"\n";}
```

Even shorter recursive function, with error reporting disabled and an empty line before real output (62 bytes):

```php
function f($n){$n&&f($n-1);for(;$i++<$n;)echo$i,' ';echo"\n";}
```

---

Just for fun, non-recursive fucntions:

```php
function f($n){for($i=0;$i<$n;print implode(' ',range(1,++$i))."\n");}    // 70 bytes
function f($n){for(;@$i<$n;print implode(' ',range(1,@++$i))."\n");}      // 68 bytes, hiding notices.
function f($n){for(;$i<$n;print implode(' ',range(1,++$i))."\n");}        // 66 bytes, error reporting disabled.
```

Comment: 45 bytes: `for($a=1;@$i<$n;$a.=" ".(@++$i+print"$a\n"));`

Comment: @Austin: I've read in a comment that the code must be either a full program reading from input, or a function.
Very nice trick, it can be improved by a bit / byte: `for($a=1;@$i++<$n;$a.=" ".($i+print"$a\n"));` (44 bytes)

Comment: Ah ok, then I suppose you would do `function f($n){for($a=1;@$i++<$n;$a.=" ".($i+print"$a\n"));}`, which is 60 bytes.

Comment: Indeed. Are you OK if I edit my answer to add your solution?

Comment: Sure, go for it.

Comment: `for($a=1;$i++<$n=$_GET[n];$a.=" ".($i+print"$a\n"));` --> try this (full code, using url parameter `n` with the number)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: I've edited the answer with your idea. Using `$argv[1]` is better for the no-error version. Too bad we can't use `$argc` directly.

Comment: I have a shorter one for you, but only for PHP 4: `for($a=1;@$i++<$n=$N;$a.=" ".($i+print"$a\n"));`, pass the URL parameter `N=x`. This works only on PHP<4.2 because of the directive `register_globals` (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) which automatically registers the variables in `$_POST`, `$_GET` and so on to the current code automatically. `$_GET['Z']` will be registed as the variable `$Z`. This value defaults to `on` on those old versions. To work for PHP<5.3, you have to create a `php.ini` file with `register_globals=on`

Comment: @BenoitEsnard You have to do `$argv[1]*1` or `$argv[1]+0`, otherwise it will print `1` if you give it `0` when it is supposed to print nothing.  At least, that's what happens in PHP 5.5.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes removing unnecessary `$n=` in loop condition.

Comment: @Austin this can be done by changing `@$i++=` to `@++$i<=` so only one character must be added.

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
ri{),:)S*N}/
```

**How it works**:

```
ri{       }/     "Run the block input number of times with iteration index from 0 to N-1";
   )             "Increment the iteration index (making it 1 to N)";
    ,            "Get an array of 0 to iteration index";
     :)          "Increment each of the above array members by 1";
       S*        "Join all above array numbers with space";
         N       "Add a new line. After all iterations, things are automatically printed";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%7B)%2C%3A)S*N%7D%2F&input=5)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6) 49 <s>52</s>

Such a simple task, I wonder if this can be made shorter in JS (Update: yes, using recursion)

Recursive 49

```js
f=n=>alert((r=w=>n-i++?w+'\n'+r(w+' '+i):w)(i=1))
```

Iteraive 52

```js
f=n=>{for(o=r=i=1;i++<n;o+='\n'+r)r+=' '+i;alert(o)}
```

Comment: Where can I test this? I cant seem to find any ES6 playgrounds that accepts this

Comment: @KristofferSall-Storgaard Firefox supports ES6 be default. So Firefox Console.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
VQjdr1hhN
```

Really thought that this can be done shorter, but it doesn't seem so.

Try it [online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQjdr1hhN&input=5&debug=0).

```
            Q = input()
VQ          For N in [0, 1, ..., Q-1]:
    r1hhN       create list [1, ..., N+1+1-1]
  jd            print joined with spaces
```

Comment: An alternative 9: `VQaYhNjdY`. If only `a` returned the list, then something like `VQjdaYhN` would be 8.

Comment: `a` briefly used to return the appended list.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pyth, so could you elaborate why `N+1+1-1`?

Comment: @Sieg `r` is the Python-range function, therefore the -1 (`r1N` creates the list `[1, 2, ..., N-1]`). But in the Nth iteration of the loop, I want the list `[1, 2, ..., N+1]`, therefore I need to add `2` to `N`. `r1hhN` translates directly to `range(1, N+1+1)`. Another possibility would be `r1+N2` (`range(1, N+2)`).

Comment: Or even `mhdhN`, but that's a complete different approach.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>85</s> 84 bytes

This is surprisingly short in Java.

```java
void a(int a){String b="";for(int c=0;c++<a;System.out.println(b+=(c>1?" ":"")+c));}
```

Indented:

```java
void a(int a){
    String b="";
    for(int c=0;
        c++<a;
        System.out.println(
                b+=(c>1?" ":"")+c
        ));
}
```

1 byte thanks to Bigtoes/Geobits

Comment: You can save one by moving the `b+=...` into `println(b+=...)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <strike>40</strike> 37 + 3 = 40 bytes

```
&1>:&:&)?;1\
(?v:n" "o1+>}:{:@
ao\~1+
```

Once again, ><> does decently well at another number printing exercise. Run with the `-v` flag for input, e.g.

```
py -3 fish.py -v 4
```

### Explanation

```
&               Put n in register
1               Push 1 (call this "i")

[outer loop]

:&:&)?          If i > n...
;                 Halt
1                 Else push 1 (call this "j")

[inner loop]

}:{:@(?         If j > i...
~1+ao             Pop j, print newline, increment i and go to start of outer loop
:n" "o1+          Else print j, print a space, increment j and go to start of inner loop
```

Answer (score 3):

## Prolog - 119

```prolog
h(N):-setof(X,(between(1,N,K),setof(Y,between(1,K,Y),X)),[L]),k(L),nl,fail.
k([A|B]):-write(A),(B=[];write(" "),k(B)).
```

Answer (score 3):

**Python 2 - <del>62</del> <del>54</del> 65 bytes**

```python
def f(n):
 for x in range(n):print' '.join(map(str,range(1,x+2)))
```

Comment: The number `n` should be given as input to the program, not initialized in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Was not sure about that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. What I meant is that you must actually define `N` by doing `N=input()` or something similar, so that your program can be run as such. [Here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) is a Meta discussion on the topic.

Comment: So this would be right, right?

Comment: Looks good now!

Answer (score 3):

### J, 9 characters

As a tacit, monadic verb.

```
[:":\1+i.
```

- `i. y` – the numbers from `0` to `y - 1`.
- `1 + i. y` – the numbers from `1` to  `y`.
- `": y` – the vector `y` represented as a string.
- `":\ y` – each prefix of `y` represented as a string.
- `":\ 1 + i. y` – each prefix of the numbers from `1` to `y` represented as a matrix of characters.

Comment: Now that's quite smart. +1

Comment: This is more J-esque but doesn't it violate the rule about there being no trailing spaces on each line?

Comment: @miles Indeed it does! Anything else would be very complicated.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 - 72

```
>>> def p(N):print'\n'.join(' '.join(map(str,range(1,i+2)))for i in range(N))
... 
>>> p(5)
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: For answers on this site, you should write a complete program or function. And you should print the result to stdout, or return them from a function. N should be read from input or taken as a function parameter, not predefined as a variable.

Comment: @user23013 OK,fixed!

Comment: The function definition needs to be included in the byte count, so I don't think this is 61. It's probably in your best interest to call the function something short, like `p`. On another note, you can remove two spaces - one between `print` and `'\n'` and the other between `)))` and `for`.

Comment: @Sp3000 OK,thanks for attention! fixed!;)

Comment: 72: `def p(N):print'\n'.join(' '.join(map(str,range(1,i+2)))for i in range(N))`

Comment: You forgot the other two changes.

Comment: @Sieg Yes! nice, as im new here i don't attention to this tiny stuffs ;)

Answer (score 2):

## C (with no loops, yeah!) - 72 bytes

```
b(n,c){if(n){b(n-1,32);printf("%d%c",n,c);}}r(n){if(n){r(n-1);b(n,10);}}
```

This creates a function `r(n)` that can be used this way:

```
main(){ r(5); }
```

See it in action, here [on tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUXFpbmVERldCTmM)

It requires a very few tricks easily explained.
I think it can be greatly improved.

Comment: Actually it's 75 bytes, not 74. However, you can cut it down to 72 bytes by replacing ' ' with 32 and '\n' with 10: `b(n,c){if(n){b(n-1,32);printf("%d%c",n,c);}}r(n){if(n){r(n-1);b(n,10);}}`

Comment: Pretty nice trick, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I did my best to one up you in the C category, but I couldn't make anything shorter! So I decided to shorten yours instead.

Comment: 64 bytes `b(n,c){n&&b(n-1,32)^printf("%d%c",n,c);}r(n){n&&r(n-1)^b(n,10);}`  [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nLuK6y9fvpI8zFll)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 28

Reads the parameter from stdin.

```
@x=1..$_,print"@x
"for 1..<>
```

From the command line:

```
perl -E'$,=$";say 1..$_ for 1..<>'
```

but I don't now how to count that (probably between 25 and 29).

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RRıðj
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kp9S7IKlpSVpuhbLg4KObDy8IWtJcVJyMVRswSJDAwgLAA)

##### Explanation

```python
RRıðj  # Implicit input    ->  4
R      # Range [1..n]      ->  [1,2,3,4]
 R     # Range of each     ->  [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
  ı    # To each list:
   ðj  #  Join by spaces   ->  ["1","1 2","1 2 3","1 2 3 4"]
       # Join by newlines  ->  "1\n1 2\n1 2 3\n1 2 3 4"
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 34 bytes

```julia
~n=1:n.|>x->println(join(1:x,' '))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7P1tAqT6/GrkLXrqAoM68kJ08jKz8zT8PQqkJHXUFdU/N/nYGCsoJfvkJ@aUlBaQlXnaHRfwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Python

```
import string
N,s=int(input()),list(string.digits)
for i in range(1,N+1):
    print(' '.join(s[1:i+1]))
```

Comment: Doesn't this fail if N >= 10?

Comment: @Sieg Yes you're right. I just learning Python, was looking for way to convert list of int to list of strings.

Comment: 63 bytes: `for i in range(int(input())):print(' '.join("123456789"[:i+1]))` - Note that strings are treated as lists.

Answer (score 1):

## Go, <del>93</del> <del>81</del> <del>78</del> <del>93</del> 90 bytes

```go
func r(n int)(s string){s=string(n+48);if n!=1{s=r(n-1)+" "+s};println(s);return}
```

### Current ungolfed

```go
func r(n int) (s string) {
    // Convert n to a string, we do not have to initialize s since
    // we hijacked the return value.
    // Numbers in the ascii table starts at 48
    s = string(n | 48)
    // Unless we are on our last iteration, we need previous iterations,
    // a space and our current iteration
    if n != 1 {
        // Collect the result of previous iteration for output
        s = r(n-1) + " " + s
    }
    println(s)
    // We can use a naked return since we specified the
    // name of our return value in the function signature
    return
}
```

If we need to handle N > 9 we can use the following at 78 bytes, however it requires importing the `fmt` package.

```
func r(n int)(s string){s=Sprint(n);if n!=1{s=r(n-1)+" "+s};Println(s);return}
```

If we include the import statement I'm now back at my initial <del>93</del> <del>92</del> 90 bytes

```
import."fmt";func r(n int)(s string){s=Sprint(n);if n>1{s=r(n-1)+" "+s};Println(s);return}
```

Test it online here: http://play.golang.org/p/BWLQ9R6ilw

The version with `fmt` is here: http://play.golang.org/p/hQEkLvpiqt

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about the string cast, but any attempts to turn it into a byte array just makes it longer

Comment: The main problem I see is that it doesn't work for n>9. You can save a byte by changing `!=` to `>`, though.

Comment: @Bigtoes, fixed now, I dont know if I'm supposed to count the `import` statement though

Comment: I know they're counted for the languages I'm more familiar with, so most likely yes. Sucks, I know :)

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript 14

```
,{2+,1>' '*n}/
```

Expects the input number to be present on the stack.

Online example: [link](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MTAKCix7MissMT4nICcqbn0v&run=true)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl: 34 characters

```perl
print"@$_\n"for map[1..$_],1..$_;
```

This code gets the input number supplied through the special variable `$_`.

Comment: Most brackets are redundant here: `print"@$_\n"for map[1..$_],1..$_` also works.

Comment: I adjusted the code.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 89 characters

```c
// 90 characters
f(int n){int a=1,b;for(;n--;++a){for(b=0;b<a;++b)printf("%c%d",(!!b)*' ',b+1);puts("");}}
```

To eliminate confusion about `puts("");`. This simply prints a newline character (as seen [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/)):

> Notice that puts not only differs from fputs in that it uses stdout as destination, but it also appends a newline character at the end automatically (which fputs does not).

I got it slightly shorter with @TheBestOne's java algorithm:

```c
// 89 characters
f(int a){char b[999]="",*p=b+1;int c=0;for(;a--&&(sprintf(b,"%s %d",b,++c)&&puts(p)););}
```

Comment: `puts("");` does nothing. You can use `char b[999]=""` instead of `char b[999]={0}` to save 1 character.

Comment: `puts("");` prints a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clip](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip), 16

```
Jm[ijkw,1iwS},1n
```

### Explanation

```
J                   .- join with newlines                           -.
 m[i        },1n    .- map numbers from 1 to numeric value of input -.
    jkw   wS        .- join with spaces                             -.
       ,1i          .- numbers from 1 to index                      -.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash+coreutils, 26 bytes

```
seq $1|sed "x;G;s/\n/ /;h"
```

- `seq` simply generates the numbers 1 to n
- `sed` saves the entire output for a given line in the hold space, and then appends the next line to it.

Answer (score 1):

## ZX / Sinclair BASIC - 39 bytes

ZX Basic uses 1 byte per keyword (all the uppercase words), so helps to keep the byte size down a bit...

```
1 INPUT n:FOR i=1 TO n:FOR j=1 TO i:PRINT j;" ";:NEXT j:PRINT:NEXT i
```

Using n = 8

[image]

Comment: Nice. But ZX basic uses 6 more hidden bytes for each numeric literal (a common trick was `VAL("1")` (6 bytes as VAL is 1) insted of `1` (7 bytes))

Answer (score 1):

## R, 28

```
for(i in 1:scan())print(1:i)
```

Comment: The output is incorrect for an input value of 0. Also, it's unclear whether the leading `[1]` on each line is in violation of the spec.

Comment: @AlexA. if you look closely at the question you'll see my comment asking what behavior should be for n=0. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I saw the comment. The thing is that this doesn't print nothing for 0, it prints `1; 1 0`. (Pretend `;` is a line break.)

Comment: You might want to also consider using `cat(1:i,"\n")`. Even though it's slightly longer than `print(1:i)`, it doesn't include a leading `[1]` on each line.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 28 bytes

```
Input N
For(I,1,N
randIntNoRep(1,N->L1
SortA(L1
Disp L1
End
```

Comment: This does not output as the format indicates; rather, the array is displayed, brackets and all, on the homescreen.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <strike>62</strike> 57 bytes

```
e=enumFromTo 1
f=putStr.unlines.map(unwords.map show.e).e
```

Point-free style. Usage example:

```
Prelude> f 5
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Doing `e=enumFromTo 1` saves 7 bytes.

Comment: @Zgarb: Thanks, but if I swap out `enumFromTo 1`, I have to give the main function a name, too, so it's 5 bytes. Without the name it would be a `let` construct: `let e=enumFromTo 1 in (putStr.unlines.map(unwords.map show.e).e) 5`

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 130 bytes

To provide N, provide that many arguments on the command-line (the arguments don't matter, just the count of arguments).

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#define printf P
int main(int c, char**){if(int x=c-1){main(x--,0);P("1");for(;x;--x){P(" %d",c-x);}P("\n");}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# - 94 bytes

Written as an anonymous function that returns a string, which doesn't seem to be disallowed by the spec.

```cs
n=>String.Join("\n\n",Enumerable.Range(1,n).Select(l=>String.Join(" ",Enumerable.Range(1,l))))
```

Here's an ungolfed version (comments are read in BDCA order):

```cs
n =>
    String.Join("\n\n",                    //...then join it together with newlines.
        Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(l => //For each l from 1 to n, ...
                String.Join(" ",              //...and join it with spaces, ...
                    Enumerable.Range(1, l)    //...get the range from 1 to l, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <strike>73</strike> <strike>65</strike> 62 bytes

```scala
(n:Int)=>print(1 to n map(1 to _ mkString " ") mkString "\n")
```

**Ungolfed**

```scala
def printNumberTriangle(n: Int): Unit = {
  def rowString(m: Int): String = 1.to(m).mkString(" ")
  print(1.to(n).map(rowString).mkString("\n"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 32

```
Print@Row[Range@i," "]~Do~{i,#}&
```

Comment: How about `TableForm[Range/@Range@#]&`?

Comment: Shorter: `Grid[Range/@Range@#]&`

Comment: And it even looks better. :) (I keep forgetting about `Grid`.)

Comment: But I'm not sure if there is no trailing space at the end of each line.

Comment: Oh good point. :(

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 73

```
n=5;for(i=1,s='';i<=n;i++)for(j=1;j<=i;j++)s+=j+(j==i?"\n":' ');alert(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Excel VBA, 97 bytes

```
n = InputBox("n")
For i = n To 1 Step -1
For j = n To 1 Step -1
Cells(i, j) = j
Next j
n = n - 1
Next i
```

When executed you are prompted for n and the resulting triangles are displayed on the spread sheet:
[image: output]

Comment: Optimized version to taking autoformatting into account, 74 Bytes `Sub f(n)`
`For i=n To 1 Step -1`
`For j=1To n`
`Cells(i, j)=j`
`Next j`
`n=n-1`
`Next i`
`End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 92 bytes

```
var x=function(o){for(var r=1;o>=r;r++){for(var a="",f=1;r>=f;f++)a+=f+" ";console.log(a)}};
```

usage: `x(5)`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think you accidentally put a stray `\`` in there. Also, [unnamed functions are generally allowed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-function-literals-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for/1503#1503), so you can omit the `var x`. Even if not, you could shorten it to `function x(o)...`. If you'd use the ES6 standard, you could shorten it even further by using [arrow notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You can also leave out all the `var`s ... we don't care about good style here. ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thank you for the good pointers :)

Answer (score 1):

## awk, 27 bytes

```awk
{for(n=$0;n>=$i=++i;)print}
```

Got it working with some tweaks.

#### Example usage and output

```
me@home:~$ echo 0 | awk '{for(n=$0;n>=$i=++i;)print}'
me@home:~$ echo 1 | awk '{for(n=$0;n>=$i=++i;)print}'
1
me@home:~$ echo 2 | awk '{for(n=$0;n>=$i=++i;)print}'
1
1 2
me@home:~$ echo 12 | awk '{for(n=$0;n>=$i=++i;)print}'
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 1):

**C,88 bytes**

```
f(n,i,j,t){i=j=1;for(;i<=n;){t=j;printf("%d%c",t,j==i?(++i&&(j=1))*'\n':(++j||1)*' ');}}
```

Usage:

```
f(10);

1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 76

```
time {set p "";set j 1;while \$j<=[incr i] {set p $p\ $j;incr j};puts $p} $n
```

Testable on http://rextester.com/FPJXC1708

Is the first line accountable? It is not part of the algorithm, only serves for acquiring input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 24 bytes

```
{say ~$_ for [\,] 1..$_}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, 3 bytes

```
RRG
```

How it works:

```
RRG
R     Inclusive Range, 3 -> [1, 2, 3]
 R    Inclusive Range for all elements, [1, 2, 3] -> [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
  G   Attempt to format as grid
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x8U5P7//38TAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 4 bytes

```
:Lh_
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@2/lkxH///9/QwMA)

This works by building the stack up to the final line, step-by-step, and printing the stages:

```
:    \ Input times do (this consumes input):
Lh   \  Push stack length + 1
_    \  Print stack items, space separated.
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 14 bytes

```
":@>@<@:>:\@i.
```

Usage:

```
   f =. ":@>@<@:>:\@i.
   f 5
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

**Explanation**:

```
   i.4                      N.B.  i.n = list of numbers up to n
0 1 2 3

   >:@i.4                   N.B.  >:n = increment n
1 2 3 4

   >:\@i.4                  N.B.  >:\n = increment prefixes of n
1 0 0 0
1 2 0 0
1 2 3 0
1 2 3 4

   <@:>:\@i.4               N.B.   < = Box, <@:>:\ = Box the incremented prefixes of n
+-+---+-----+-------+
|1|1 2|1 2 3|1 2 3 4|
+-+---+-----+-------+

   ":@>@<@:>:\@i.4          N.B.   ":@> = String format each opened box (ensures no zeros or spaces appear at the end of each line). 
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

## Noether, 39 bytes

```
I~A{A0>}{A(i1+~i(j1+~jP" "P£)"
"P0~ji)}
```

[**Try it here!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=SX5Be0EwPn17QShpMSt-aShqMSt-alAiICJQwqMpIgoiUDB-amkpfQ)

**Explanation:**

```
I~A   - Push User Input onto the stack and store in variable A
{A0>} - If A>0
{     - Then do
A(    - loop until top of stack equals A
i1+~i - Increment i
(     - loop until top of stack equals i
j1+~j - Increment j
P     - Print top of stack (j)
" "   - Push the string " " onto stack
P     - Print top of stack (" ")
£     - Pop top of stack
)     - End loop
"\n"  - Push the string "\n" onto stack
P     - Print top of stack
0~j   - Set variable j to zero
i     - Push i onto stack
)     - End loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 40 bytes

```forth
: f 1+ 1 do i 1+ 1 do i . loop cr loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRhqKxgqpOQrZCKx9BRy8vMLFJKLILT1f1OFtP8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 4 bytes

```
ɾɾvṄ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiyb7JvnbhuYQiLCIiLCI1Il0=)

#### Explained

```
ɾɾvṄ
rr   # range over range over input
  v  # vectorise
   Ṅ # join list by spaces
```

`j` flag joins by newlines

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 30 bytes

```arturo
$=>[loop map&=>[@1..&]=>print]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?eXT02B)

Answer (score 0):

## C++

```
int main()
{
   cout << "Enter N:";
   int N;
   cin >> N;

    for(int i=1; i <= N; i++)
    {
         for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
              cout << j;
            }
       cout << endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw, this is code-golf (writing a program in the least amount of characters). Therefore something like `cout << "Enter N:";` is not necessary. Also you can save a lot of chars, if you remove the whitespace, remove `return 0;`, ...

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2 - <strike>60</strike> <strike>61</strike> 53 bytes**

```
k='1'
for i in range(2,input()+2):print k;k+=' '+`i`
```

With thanks to Sp3000

Comment: Had the indents in my code, lost them when I copied it to the post. And thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Also one more thing: by [default](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info), code golf implies full program or function, so you can't assume `N` is already defined (maybe `i<=input()`?). On a side note though, you can save a few bytes by replacing `str(i)` with `<backtick>i<backtick>` :)

Comment: @Sp3000 `\`\\`i\\`\`` seems to work: `\`i\``.

Comment: @user23013 `\`i\``. Ah thanks, so it does.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript, 83**

Not to happpy about this one

```
n=9;r='';for(i=1;i<n+2;i++){for(a=1;a<i;a++){r+=a+' '}r=r.slice(0,-1)+'\n'}alert(r)
```

Pretty straight forwards

`r='';` so javascript doesn't add the value as numbers

`r.slice(0,-1)+'\n'`remove last space and add a line end

Edit: info

First I was trying to use A030512(int seq) but that failed n>10

Answer (score 0):

## k, 8

```
1+!:'1+!
```

<strike>I need to add 27 characters so I'm just going to type some nonsense here.</strike>

```
k)!5
0 1 2 3 4

k)1+!5
1 2 3 4 5

k)!:'1+!5
,0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4

k)1+!:'1+!5
,1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Wouldn't a brief explanation be a lot more fun than some nonsense?

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - 51

```
r=->(n){(1..n).each{|i|puts (1..i).to_a.join(" ")}}
```

Sample output:

```
r[5] # 1
     # 1 2
     # 1 2 3
     # 1 2 3 4
     # 1 2 3 4 5

r[7] # 1
     # 1 2
     # 1 2 3
     # 1 2 3 4
     # 1 2 3 4 5
     # 1 2 3 4 5 6
     # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: If you aren't pedantic enough to care, trim 3 bytes by changing `puts` to `p` - but this surrounds every line in the output with `"`

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 116 bytes

```vba
Function n(m As Integer)
If m > 0 Then 
For a = 1 To m 
n = n & " " & a 
Next 
Debug.Print n(m - 1) 
End If 
End Function
```

Comment: Doesn't this generate a leading new line and a leading space?

Comment: oh leading space isn't allowed?  I thought only trailing space is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

## And the loser is... Pascal! <s>178</s> 148 bytes

Sidenote: this isn't golfed at all, besides newlines and spaces. I haven't coded in Pascal for more than 10 years, so I used it just for the memories.

Golfed:

```
program p;procedure p(n:integer);var i,j:integer;begin for i:=1 to n do begin for j:=1 to i do begin write(j); end; writeln; end end;begin p(5);end.
```

Ungolfed:

```
program p;
procedure p(n:integer);
var i,j:integer;
begin
    for i:=1 to n do begin
        for j:=1 to i do begin
            write(j);
        end;
        writeln;
    end
end;
begin
    p(5);
end.
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to output the spaces. Also there is no need for semicolons before `end`.

Comment: Right... the spaces. I didn't remember that semicolons before `end` were optional, two extra bytes could be golfed there

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2 - <del>57</del> 61 bytes**

Had another idea.
Only bad thing is the leading space.

```python
def f(n):
 s=''
 for x in range(n):s+=' %s'%(x+1);print s[1:]
```

example output:

```python
>>> def f(n):
...  s=''
...  for x in range(n):s+=' %s'%(x+1);print s[1:]
... 
>>> f(8)
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Change `print s` to `print s[1:]`. This gets rid of the first char in the string

Answer (score 0):

**Golfscript - 41 chars**

```
"#{STDIN.gets}"~.0={}{)}if,{,{)}%" "*}%n*
```

How it works:

"#{STDIN.gets}" -> Read a string from input

"~" -> Evaluate the input

".0=" -> Create a clone of the input and check if it's zero

"{}{)}if" -> If it's zero, do nothing, else add one to the number

",{,{)}%" "*}%" -> Create a list from 0 to N, loop through it and create new lists and do other stuff that I don't have time to explain.

"n*" -> Display it nicely

Answer (score 0):

## ARM assembly 485 bytes

```
.global main
main:
    mov r0, #10
    mov r1, #1
    bl triangle

    mov r0, #10
    bl putchar

    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

triangle:
    cmp r1, r0
    movgt pc, lr
    push {r0,r1,lr}
    mov r0, r1
    mov r1, #1
    bl row
    mov r0, #10
    bl putchar
    pop {r0,r1,lr}
    add r1, r1, #1
    b triangle

row:
    cmp r1, r0
    movgt pc, lr
    push {r0,r1,lr}
    ldr r0, =numFormat
    bl printf
    pop {r0,r1,lr}
    add r1, r1, #1
    b row

numFormat:
    .asciz "%d "
```

called using the subroutine `triangle`, register `r0` holds the limit and `r1` holds the starting value.

tested on Raspberry Pi and Android

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8 - 293 chars

Golfed:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
public class T{public static void main(String[] a){int n=10;System.out.println(IntStream.range(1,n+1).boxed().map(i->IntStream.range(1,i+1).boxed().map(j->""+j).collect(joining(" "))).collect(joining("\n")));}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
    import java.util.stream.*;
    import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

    public class T {
        public static void main(String[] a){
            int n=10;

            System.out.println(
                 IntStream.range(1,n+1)
                          .boxed()
                          .map(i -> IntStream.range(1,i+1)
                                             .boxed()
                                             .map(j -> ""+j)
                                             .collect(joining(" ")))
                          .collect(joining("\n")));
        }
    }
```

Example output, n = 10:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP (65 bytes):

This is pretty simple to do in php:

```php
for(;$i++<$_GET[n];$_[]=join(' ',range(1,$i)));echo@join('
',$_);
```

This probably may output an empty string or the '\0' char or worst if you use `0` (there is no control on it).

This is because `$_` will be `null`when you use `0` and PHP will output `null` (which may output any of the said before).

---

There is another aproach (61 bytes):

```php
foreach(range(1,$_GET[n])as$v)echo join(' ',range(1,$v))."
";
```

But it can't handle the `0` in the expected way.

Answer (score 0):

### Dyalog APL, 11 characters

Assumes `⎕IO←1`.

```
(⍕↑)⍤0 1⍨⍳⎕
```

- `⍕⍵` – `⍵` represented as a string.
- `⍺↑⍵` – `⍺` items taken from `⍵`.
- `⍺(⍕↑)⍵` – `⍺` items taken from `⍵`, the result represented as a string.
- `⍺(⍕↑)⍤0 1⍵` – The previous expression, but executed for each item in `⍺` and each vector in `⍵`.
- `(⍕↑)⍤0 1⍨⍵` – The previous expression with both arguments taken from `⍵`.
- `(⍕↑)⍤0 1⍨⍳⍵` – The previous expression applied to the integers from `1` to `⍵`.
- `(⍕↑)⍤0 1⍨⍳⎕` – The previous expression with input taken from the user.

Answer (score 0):

## K, 17 bytes

```
(`0:" "/$1+!)'1+!
```

Doing this sort of formatted output isn't very convenient in K. I used the "join" form of `/` from k5 to join elements of each vector with spaces. Try it with [oK](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html?run=%20(%600%3A%22%20%22%2F%241%2B!)'1%2B!5%3B).

A nice thing about this solution is that it is in "tacit" form, so there's no need to create a function wrapper. Just append the argument N and suppress the result with `;`:

```
  (`0:" "/$1+!)'1+!5;
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

**Powershell v2  number of Characters : 567**

```
   function Build-Triangle 
    {
         [CmdletBinding()]
         param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
            [int]$n
        )

        begin {}
        process 
        {
            [int]$cnt = 1
            if ( $n -gt 0 )
            {
                while ( $cnt -le $n )
                {
                    $string += $cnt.ToString() + " "
                    Write-Output -InputObject $string
                    $cnt++
                }                
            }
        }
        end {}
    }


    Build-Triangle -n 10 | Measure-Object 
    0 | Build-Triangle 
    11 | Build-Triangle  
    # just for kicks make the triangle upside down
    11 | Build-Triangle  | Sort-Object -Descending
    # find out how big the function is
    Get-Content Function:\Build-Triangle | Measure-Object -Word -Character -Line
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is code golf. Please show some effort to reduce the number of bytes in your code (single-letter variable names, no comments, no unnecessary whitespace would be a start).

Answer (score 0):

### C# - 92 bytes

```
void f(int n){for(int i=0;i++<n;)Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",Enumerable.Range(1,i)));}
```

Nothing fancy, just a packed function.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 73 chars

Not even trying to compare with the others here, just your typical first post:

```
for(n=prompt(),i=1;n>=i;i++){var l="";for(j=1;j<=i;j++)l+=" "+j;alert(l)}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies because it's alerting *n* times, which is not the same as outputting a 'right angle triangle' of the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell -  <s>42</s> 32bytes

*Edit: AdmBorkBork reports that we can save many bytes by using a complete script, and assuming a default delimiter!*

```
 param($n)0..$n-gt0|%{"$(1..$_)"}
```

Never done any serious PowerShell, just felt I might learn something from this, and indeed I did. *Old 42byte code:*

```
function k($n){0..$n-gt0|%{1..$_-join" "}}
```

Defines a *function* `k` which takes an input `$n`, creates a range from `0` through to `$n`, filters for entires greater than `0`, then creates a range from `1` to each remaining value, and joins these with a space. Example out:

```
PS > k 3
1
1 2
1 2 3
PS > k 0
PS >
```

Alternatively, you can define a *filter*, which will print as many triangles as you want.

```
filter z{0..$_-gt0|%{1..$_-join" "}}

PS > 3,0,2|z
1
1 2
1 2 3
1
1 2
PS >
```

Comment: Hiya! Not sure if you're still around, but you can use a full script instead of a function and use the default `$OutputFieldSeparator` to get down to 32 bytes with `param($n)0..$n-gt0|%{"$(1..$_)"}` -- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSp2mgp6eSp5teYlCjWq2komEI5MZrKtX@///f0BQA "PowerShell – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I do indeed still lurk around here, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

## Element, 20

```
_'[1+2:'.2:`\ ."\
`]
```

The main idea is that the stacks contain a string and a number. We repeatedly increment the number and append it to the string, printing the result.  Given that Element has zero support for arrays, I think this is a very decent score.

Since most people are probably unfamiliar with this language, Element is a golfing language I created in 2012.  You can see the most updated interpreter, written in Perl, [here](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element).

To make the explanation easier, I'll replace the newline with an `L`.

```
_'[1+2:'.2:`\ ."\L`]
_'                    input a number and put it onto the control stack
  [                ]  this is a FOR loop
   1+                 increment the number.  An empty stack is zero.
     2:               make a second copy of it
       '              put one copy on the control stack to save it
        .             append the other copy to the end of the string
         2:           make a second copy of the new string
           `          output one of them
            \ .       append a space to the other
               "      put the number from earlier pack onto the main stack
                \L`   output a newline, but the L should be an actual newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 60 bytes

One byte less than current best in Python 2, so I've decided to post it.

```
def f(x):
 if x:f(x-1);print" ".join(map(str,range(1,x+1)))
```

Usage:

```
f(5)

1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Three slightly different approaches

## Ruby, 37 bytes

```
f=->n{n.times{|i|puts [*1..i+1]*" "}}
```

## Ruby, 38 bytes

```
f=->n{puts (1..n).map{|i|[*1..i]*" "}}
```

## Ruby, 40 bytes

```
f=->n{([*1..n+1]*" ").scan(/ /){puts$`}}
```

Answer (score 0):

### UniBasic 50 Bytes

```
S='';INPUT N;FOR I=1 TO N;S:=I;CRT S;S:=' ';NEXT I
```

Ungolfed:

```
S=''
INPUT N
FOR I=1 TO N
  S:=I
  CRT S
  S:=' '
NEXT I
```

Answer (score 0):

## q, 18 bytes

```
1+til each 1+til n
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 63

```
for m=1:input('');fprintf(['1' repmat(' %d',1,m-1) 10],2:m);end
```

Not the best, but because of the requirements on spaces, functions like `num2str` and `disp` can't be used as they produce too many.

Run the code and enter the number when prompted (~=STDIN). It will then print the number triangle.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 77 Bytes

```
function(n){for(i=1;i<=n;i++){a='';for(j=1;j<=i;j++)a+=j+' ';console.log(a)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LL»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx@fQ7v//DQ0B)

**Explanation:**

```python
L      # Create a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 L     # Map each integer `i` to a list in the range [1, `i`]
  »    # Join the list of lists by newlines,
       # which implicitly also joins the inner lists by a single space
       # (and output it implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>97</s> 93 bytes

```
listen to N
X's 0
while N-X
build X up
O's 1
Y's 1
while X-Y
let Y be+1
let O be+" "+Y

say O
```

[Try it](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

### Original, 97 bytes

```
listen to N
X's 0
while N-X
build X up
O's 1
cut O
while X-O
rock O+1 in O

join O with " "
say O
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2 bytes (4 nibbles)

```
.,$,
```

```
.,$,        # full program
.,$,$       # with implicit arg added
.           # map over
 ,          # range from 1..
  $         # input
   ,        # getting the range from 1..
    $       # each number
```

Fortunately, Nibbles' default formatting for lists-of-lists is a happy match to the required output.

[image]