# Sum the numbers on standard in

Tags: code-golf, string, arithmetic

Consider a stream/file with one integer per line. For example:

```
123
5
99
```

Your code should output the sum of these numbers, that is `227`.

The input format is strictly one integer per line. You cannot, for example, assume the input is on one line as an array of integers.

You can take input either from STDIN, in form of a filename, or a file with a name of your choice; you can choose which one. No other ways of getting input are allowed.

The input will contain at least one integer. You can assume all integers are non-negative and that their total sum is less than `232`.

Comment: Is there a trailing newline?  Is that newline optional?

Comment: Hi! I downvoted this challenge because it goes against our [community standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963) for acceptable input/output formats by having a restrictive input format.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork and I discussed this at length in the chat room. We have agreed to disagree :)

Comment: As the author of the things-to-avoid of [cumbersome I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/20260) and [arbitrarily overriding defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8065/20260), I want to defend this challenge on those grounds. Here, the processing input is the meat of the challenge, not extra work that distracts from the main challenge. It's not "add numbers" with weird I/O requirements, it's "do this I/O" with adding as a step. Overruling the standard I/O is necessary  for answers not to shortcut across the main task.

Comment: @ais523 [Ahem.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113714/12012)

Comment: @Dennis: OK, I didn't think of that. Still fairly ridiculous that you have to go to those lengths, though.

Comment: Why can't function input be used?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
|O
```

Explanation:

```
|   Get input as array
 O  Sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@1/j//@/oZExlymXpSUA)

Comment: That's ridiculous :)

Comment: Does this read from standard in?

Comment: @Lembik it does.

Comment: I believe your 2 byte answer was first. You are the winner!  (Unless someone finds a 1 byte answer.)

Comment: @Lembik Or a 0 byte answer....

Comment: @SparklePony Write a compiler/interpreter that compiles anything to a solution to this problem - then the submission is a 0 byte program that compiles to a solution? Sorted :)

Answer (score 22):

### Bash + coreutils, 16 bytes

```sh
xargs|tr \  +|bc
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@RWJReXFNSpBCjoKBdk5T8/7@hkTGXKZelJQA)**

There are two spaces after the `\`. This works for negative numbers as well.

**Explanation:**

```sh
xargs             # known trick to turn newlines into spaces, while adding a
                  #trailing newline when printing the result (needed for bc)
|tr \  +          # turn spaces into '+'s
|bc               # calculates the sum
```

You may wonder why `tr \\n +|bc` isn't better, since it turns newlines directly into '+'s. Well, that has 2 unforeseen errors:

- if the input has a trailing newline, then it is converted to a trailing '+', hence there is no number after it to perform the addition
- and the most weird issue is that bc requires a trailing newline after the input, but you just replaced all of the input newlines with '+'s.

Comment: I like this.  It's nice and clever.

Comment: Could you use tr \\n + Instead without xargs?

Comment: @Lembik Do you mean `tr \\n +|bc`? If so, then please see the updated explanation. Good question.

Comment: `paste -s -d+|bc` is 15 bytes

Comment: @DavidConrad The use of `paste` is shown in another bash answer here. No harm keeping both. Thank you for the comment anyway.

Comment: Does this work if there is only one line?

Comment: @Lembik Didn't considered that case, but fortunately the script still works. `xargs|tr \  +` in this case does nothing, and bc receives the number and prints it back.

Comment: @seshoumara I agree. I hadn't seen that other answer yet when I commented. Cheers.

Comment: This is not bash specific, so should read "sh + POSIX utils"

Comment: @Jens I'm glad that it works on other shells as well, thanks for the info, but I'll keep bash in the title, since it is better known and since it's the system I tested on.

Answer (score 14):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
Us
```

This expects the input in a text file called `defin`.

*Gif or it didn't happen*:

[image]

Or [**try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQkpqWmfc/P7kksSxVQVe3ILEkQ0E/v6BEPzexJAcokFqWmKOgBOaEFiv9/29oZMxlymVpCQA) (*thanks to Dennis for the set-up!*)

#### Explanation

When a MATL program is run, if a file called `defin` is found (the name refers to "default input"), its contents are automatically loaded as text and pushed to the stack as a string before executing the code.

Function `U` evaluates the string to convert it to a column vector of numbers, and `s` computes the sum, which is implicitly displayed.

Answer (score 13):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
Nx
```

#### Explanation

```
     Implicit: parse STDIN into array of numbers, strings, and arrays
N    Get the resulting parsed array.
 x   Sum.
     Implicit: output result of last expression
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@9X8f@/oZExlymXpSUA)

Answer (score 12):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 13 bytes

```perl6
say sum lines
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@19QWqJQXJqrkJOZl1r8/7@hkTGXKZelJQA)

### Explanation

- `lines()` returns a list of lines from `$*IN` or `$*ARGFILES` a “magic” command-line input handle.
- `sum(…)` was added to Perl 6 to allow `[+] List` to be optimized for Positionals that can calculate their sum without generating all of their values like `1..100000`
  (I just thought `sum` was just too cute here to use `[+]` like I normally would)
- `say(…)` call the `.gist` method on its input, and prints it with an additional newline.

Comment: What is it perl 5?

Comment: this reads like lolcode

Comment: @Lembik it is clearly labeled as [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), which is a sister language to [Perl 5](https://perl.org).

Comment: There was a typo. I meant what is it in Perl 5?

Comment: Well `$a+=$_ for <>;print $a` works in Perl 5, but there may be a shorter way.

Comment: It is strange a Tcl guy like me ever upvoted a Perl answer!

Answer (score 12):

## Paste + bc, 13 bytes

```
paste -sd+|bc
```

Explanation:

```
paste -s        Take one line at a time from input
        d+      Joining by '+'
          |bc   Pass as expression to bc
```

Another shell answer!

Comment: Very neat and tidy.

Comment: Ooh, I had `paste -s -d+|bc` and didn't realize I could consolidate the switches. Neat!

Answer (score 10):

## C, 53 bytes

```
r;main(i){for(;~scanf("%d",&i);r+=i);printf("%d",r);}
```

Comment: C showing its credentials again :)

Comment: I feel like there should be a shorter way, but I don't see it :)

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
print(sum(map(int,open(0))))
```

Taken from [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70670/12012). I've been told this won't work on Windows.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19QlJlXolFcmquRm1igAWTr5Bek5mkYaALB//@GRsZcplyWlgA)

Comment: I learned something new!

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>11</s> 7 bytes

-4 thanks to Martin Ender

```
.*
$*
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nxaWixWX4/78hlxGXMZcJlwGXJQA)

---

Convert to unary:

```
.*
$*
```

Count the number of `1`s:

```
1
```

Comment: Interesting how Retina, as a regex based language, can do the sum in fewer bytes than the shortest bash answer posted so far. +1

Comment: Is this reading from standard in?

Comment: @Lembik Yes it is.

Comment: If input in unary was allowed, it'd be only one byte.

Comment: @mbomb007 I already tried that in sed.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 20 bytes

```
(([]){[{}]{}([])}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hER2rWR1dXRtbXQti1lbXav7/b8hlxGXMZcJlwGXJZQYA)

### Explanation

This is a golf off of [a solution made by Riley in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36243146#36243146).  His solution was:

```
([])({<{}>{}<([])>}{})
```

If your familiar with Brain-Flak this is pretty self-explanatory.  It pushes the stack height and pops one value as it counts down, at the end it pushes the sum of all the runs.

It is a pretty good golf but he zeros both `{}` and `([])` however these will have a values that only differ by one so if instead we remove the masks and make one of the two negative they should nearly cancel out.

```
([])({[{}]{}([])}{})
```

Since they always differ by one we have the unfortunate circumstance where our answer is always off by the stack height.  In order to remedy this we simply move the beginning of the push to encompass the first stack height.

```
(([]){[{}]{}([])}{})
```

Comment: I thought of it as the negative pop cancels the previous height pushed (from before the loop, or the end of the previous time through), and the last height is 0 so it can be ignored.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, 40 bytes

```py
import sys;print sum(map(int,sys.stdin))
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 9 bytes

8 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
$\+=$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@K8So22rEl9b/f@/oZExlymXpSUA)

With `-p`, the input is read one line at a time, stored in `$_` each time. We use `$\` as accumulator, because thanks to `-p` flag, it's implicitly printed at the end. The unmatched `}{` are used so `-p` flag only prints `$\` once at the end instead of printing `$_` and `$\` at each line it reads like it normally does.

Comment: I can't even parse it! :) Explanation please.

Comment: @Lembik Here you go.

Comment: The unmatched parenthesise part is very obscure!

Comment: @Lembik Those aren't parenthesizes... They're either *French* or *Curly* *Braces* depends on who you ask, but they definitely are not `)(`

Comment: I have never heard them called French. I wonder what the French call them?

Comment: @Lembik `accolades`, apparently.

Answer (score 7):

## Pure Bash, <s>37</s> 36 bytes

*Thanks to @KevinCruijssen for a byte!*

```bash
while read a;do((b+=a));done;echo $b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@ekZmTqlCUmpiikGidkq@hkaRtm6ipCWTmpVqnJmfkK6gk/f9vaGTMZcplackFAA)

Comment: Very nice and clean.

Comment: I never program in _Bash_, but isn't it possible to remove the space between `do ((`? The [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@ekZmTqlCUmpiikGidkq@hkaRtm6ipCWTmpVqnJmfkK6gk/f9vaGTMZcplackFAA) seems to work.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yeah, it seems like it works. I use zsh as my daily shell and it doesn't work in zsh without a space, I just assumed it wouldn't work in Bash but apparently it does.

Answer (score 7):

### R,11 bytes

```
sum(scan())
```

`scan` takes the input, one number per line. And `sum`, well, sums.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 32 bytes

```
interact$show.sum.map read.lines
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@bmJlnm5lXklqUmFyiUpyRX65XXJqrl5tYoFCUmpiil5OZl1r8/7@hkTGXKZelJQA).

`interact` collects the whole input from stdin, passes it to the function given as its argument and prints the string it gets back from this function. The function is:

```
            lines   -- split input into list of lines at nl
      map read      -- convert every line to a number (read is polymorphic,
                    -- but as want to sum it later, the type checker knows
                    -- it has to be numbers)
    sum             -- sum the list of numbers
show                -- convert back to string
```

Comment: This makes me really like Haskell. In Scala, I have to do `lines.map(_.toInt)`

because sum expects some sort of numeric implicit conversion from String or in this case an explicit one.

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 22 bytes

```
<?=array_sum(file(t));
```

This assumes there is a file named "t" with a list of integers.

`file()` opens a file and returns an array with each line stored a separate element in the array. `array_sum()` sums all the elements in an array.

Answer (score 5):

## Awk, 19 bytes

```
{s+=$1}END{print s}
```

Explanation:

```
{s+=$1}                For all lines in the input, add to s
        END             End loop
           {print s}    Print s
```

Comment: "Explanation coming soon™" That'd be my new catchphrase if it weren't trademarked...

Comment: In the language of awk, [your answer](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@19drG2rYljr6udSXVCUmVeiUFz7/7@hkTGXKZelJQA) is actually only 19 bytes: `{s+=$1}END{print s}` :)

Answer (score 5):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 14 bytes

```
0[+?z2=a]dsaxp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@28QrW1fZWSbGJtSnFhR8P@/oZExlymXpSUA)

Explanation:

```
 [      ] sa   # recursive macro stored in register a, does the following:
  +            # - sum both numbers on stack
               #   (prints to stderr 1st time since there's only 1)
   ?           # - read next line, push to stack as number
    z          # - push size of stack
     2         # - push 2
      =a       # - if stack size = 2, ? yielded something, so recurse
               # - otherwise end macro (implicit)
0              # push 0 (accumulator)
         d     # duplicate macro before storing it
            x  # Call macro
             p # The sum should be on the stack now, so print it
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>38</s> 30 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(map(int,open(n)))
```

In python, files are opened by `open('filename')` (obviously). They are, however, iterables. Each time you iterate through the file, you get the next line.  So map iterates over each list, calling `int` on it, and then sums the resulting list.

Call with the filename as input. (i.e. `f('numbers.txt')`)

8 bytes saved by using `map(int, open(n))` instead of a list comprehension. Original code:

```python
lambda n:sum([int(i)for i in open(n)])
```

Comment: I believe that you can also do this with standard input by calling 'open(0)'. Not sure if that can be used to shorten your answer.

Comment: @Cole dennis already has that solution, so I'll leave my answer like this.

Comment: My mistake, sorry about that; I didn't read all the way through before coming to your answer.

Comment: @Cole it's okay, I don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 5 bytes

```
q~]1b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19YF2uY9P@/oZExlymXpSUA)

#### How it works

```
q     e# Read all input from STDIN.
 ~    e# Evaluate that input, pushing several integers.
  ]   e# Wrap the entire stack in an array.
   1b e# Convert from base 1 to integer.
      e# :+ (reduce by sum) would work as well, but 1b handles empty arrays.
```

Comment: How does `1b` sum numbers?

Comment: CJam doesn't require a canonical representation for digits-to-integer conversion; `[<x> <y> <z> <w>]<b>b` simply computes **b³x + b²y + bz + w**. When **b = 1**, this gives **x + y + z + w**.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 19 bytes

Assumes Mathematica's notebook environment.

```
Tr[#&@@@Import@"a"]
```

Expects the input to be in a file `a`.

Comment: It's a crazy language :)

Comment: @Lembik normal people would write this very readably as `Total @ Flatten @ Import @ "a"` or even `"a" // Import // Flatten // Total`. ;)

Comment: Wouldn't `Tr[#&@@@Import@#]&` also be allowed?

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ƈFÐ¿FỴVS
```

STDIN isn't really Jelly's thing...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@sw@3whEP73R7u3hIW/P@/oZExlymXpSUA)

#### How it works

```
ƈFÐ¿FỴVS  Main link. No arguments. Implicit argument: 0

  Ð¿      While loop; while the condition returns a truthy value, execute the body
          and set the return value to the result. Collect all results (including 0,
          the initial return value) in an array and return that array.
ƈ           Body: Yield a character from STDIN or [] if the input is exhausted.
 F          Condition: Flatten, mapping 0 to [], '0' to "0", and [] to [] (falsy).
    F     Flatten the result.
     Ỵ    Split at newlines.
      V   Evaluate the resulting strings.
       S  Take the sum.
```

Comment: The second `F` could be a `Ṗ` as well, for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
ṇịᵐ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9wZ/vD3d0Pt07Q/v9fydDImMuUy9JS6X8UAA)

#### Explanation

```
ṇ         Split the Input on linebreaks
 ịᵐ       Map: String to Integer
   +      Sum
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pure bash, 30

```
read -d_ b
echo $[${b//'
'/+}]
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@UmpiioJsSr5DElZqcka@gEq1SnaSvr86lrq9dG/v/v6GRMZcpl6UlAA)

- `read`s the input file in one go into the variable `b`. `-d_` tells `read` that the line delimiter is `_` instead of <kbd>newline</kbd>
- `${b//'`<kbd>newline</kbd>`'/+}` replaces the newlines in `b` with `+`
- `echo $[ ... ]` arithmetically evaluates the resulting expression and outputs it.

Comment: +1 Very nice. Is the trailing newline of a input file read as well? I ask because if it is replaced by '+', the `$[]` section will error due to a trailing '+'.

Comment: @seshoumara It appears that `read` discards final trailing newlines, even though the line delimiter is overridden to `_`.  This is perhaps a caveat of `read`, but it works well for this situation.

Comment: I am always happy to see a pure bash solution.

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 16 bytes/keystrokes

```
:%s/\n/+
C<C-r>=<C-r>"<C-h>
```

Since V is backwards compatible, you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@2@lWqwfk6evzeVs46xbZGcLJpWAZIYd1///hlxGXMZcJlwGXBb/dcsA)

Comment: Is this either reading from standard in or from a file?

Comment: Yeah, Vim might not be allowed...:(

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
s.Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@1@sF/j/v6GRMZcpl6UlAA)

```
 .Q  Read all of standard input, evaluating each line.
s    Take the sum.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 5 bytes

`add`, plus the command line flag `-s`.

For example:

```
% echo "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | jq -s add
15
```

Comment: **6 bytes**.  Since `-sadd` won't work, count the space.

Comment: @agc Correct me if I'm wrong but the code itself is `add` (3 bytes) and you have to *add* 2 bytes for the `-s` flag. The space doesn't count as the code or the flag: it's the command line separator used by the language.

Comment: @ThisGuy, Well the `-s` flag is short for "*--slurp*", (read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once), which changes both how `jq` interprets the input data, and how it runs the code.  It's not like the `-e`in `sed` which merely tells `sed` that the subsequent string is code.  The `-s` is more like a part of the `jq` language itself, and therefore that 6th byte space would be too.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>19</s> 15 bytes

Loving that new `#sum` in Ruby 2.4 :)

```
p$<.sum(&:to_i)
```

This program accepts input from either stdin or any filename(s) given as command line argument

Comment: For those of us without 2.4 (including TIO…) `p$<.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
kΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@599bvH//4ZGxlymXJaWAA)

Explanation:

```
kΣ
    (implicit input - read each line, evaluate it, and push it to the stack)
k   pop all stack elements and push them as a list
 Σ  sum
    (implicit output)
```

Answer (score 3):

## dc, 22

```
[pq]sq0[?z2>q+lmx]dsmx
```

This seems rather longer than it should be, but it is tricky to decide when the end of the file is reached.  The only way I can think of to do this is check the stack length after the `?` command.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@x9dUBhbXGgQbV9lZFeonZNbEZtSnFvx/7@hkTGXKZelJQA).

```
[pq]                    # macro to `p`rint top-of-stack, then `q`uit the program
    sq                  # save the above macro in the `q` register
      0                 # push `0` to the stack.  Each input number is added to this (stack accumulator)
       [         ]      # macro to:
        ?               # - read line of input
         z              # - push stack length to stack
          2             # - push 2 to the stack
           >q           # - if 2 > stack length then invoke macro stored in `q` register
             +          # - add input to stack accumulator
              lmx       # - load macro stored in `m` register and execute it
                  d     # duplicate macro
                   sm   # store in register `m`
                     x  # execute macro
```

Note the macro `m` is called recursively.  Modern `dc` implements tail recursion for this sort of thing, so there should be no worries about overflowing the stack.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Please note that if there isn't enough explanations it will go through **the low quality posts filter**.

Comment: @SIGSEGV no welcome necessary - I've been here a while ;-).  Yep, I was writing my explanation while you commented.  See edit.

Comment: [I owe you](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114064/56183) a byte for the trick of duplicating the macro before storing it.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>50</s> <s>45</s> 43 bytes

Pretty self-explanatory.

```python
s=0
try:
    while 1:s+=input()
except:print s
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19sa8BVUlRpxaVQnpGZk6pgaFWsbZuZV1BaoqHJlVqRnFpQYlVQlJlXolD8/7@hkTGXKZelJQA)

Comment: I think any error suffices for `break`, since programs can terminate in error by default. An unitialized variable would do.

Comment: Better yet, the `while` can be in the `try` block.

Comment: Use only 1 space before `while 1:`. If you're using tabs SE messes them up.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline If you "edit" the post you can see it's a real tab. You can also see it's a real tab on TIO. I prefer tabs to spaces.

Comment: Good to know.``

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 4 bytes

```
zbrs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyke#@1@VVFT8/78hlxGXMZcZAA)

```
z    -   input()
 b   -  int(^)
  r  - if no errors: goto start
   s - sum(stack)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [GS2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 2 bytes

```
Wd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/gs2#@x@e8v@/oZExlymXpSUA)

#### How it works

```
    (implicit) Read all input from STDIN an push it as a string.
W   Extract all integers, pushing a single array.
    For input x, this executes map(int, re.findall(r'-?\d+', x)) internally.
 d  Take the sum.
```

Answer (score 2):

### [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) + bc, 34 bytes

```sed
:
$!N
$!b
y:\n:+:
s:.*:echo &|bc:e
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@2/FpaLoB8RJXJVWMXlW2lZcxVZ6WlapyRn5Cmo1SclWqf//GxoZc5lyWVoCAA)

It is possible to do a shell call from inside sed, and as such I use bc to calculate the sum. Lines 1 to 4 only prepare the input necessary for that calculation. This works for negative numbers as well.

**Explanation:**

```sed
:                    # start reading loop
$!N                  # if not EOF, read and append a new input line to pattern
$!b                  # repeat
y:\n:+:              # turn all newlines into pluses
s:.*:echo &|bc:e     # shell call to bc with pattern as input (calculates sum)
                     # implicit printing
```

**Pure GNU sed program: 236 + 1(r flag) = 237 bytes** (as promised some time ago)

There are no data types or any math operations in sed. I have tried various methods, but it turns out that concatenating the numbers in unary format and converting the result back to decimal is the simplest way. This works for non-negative integers only, compared to the code above, however this is precisely what the challenge stated in the first place.

```sed
G;s:\n::
# concatenate current decimal number with the intermediary unary sum, if any
h;:;s:\w::2g;y:9876543210:87654321\t :;/ /!s:;|$:@:;/\s/!t;x;s:.::;x;G;s:;.*::m;s:\s::g;/\w/{s:@:&&&&&&&&&&:g;t}
# convert the decimal number to unary (using '@' as digit)
y:@:;:
# change unary digit from '@' to ';', to not interfere with above on the next cycle
h;$!d
# store intermediary unary sum and start next reading cycle if input lines left
s:^:0:;/;/{:d;s:^9+:0&:;s:.9*;:/&:;h;s:.*/::;y:0123456789:1234567890:;x;s:/.*::;G;s:\n::;s:;::;/;/td}
# convert final unary sum to decimal (result), plus implicit printing at the end
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#PY/NDoIwEITvfQpICAeMtPzT2Ys3X4JwIlEP/sQ2QYK@urhrAr10tpn9ZrocyaG7AepMEDkC@Ykm2Lapq7LIM4NVdT4A6UCHDvSOcOChczr09OLFFOBbaJQmwFVYDjixZ9SzY3e8HX71HzUJQXKjcFAOPQwDSc8YeLe3O5hYGqU2IWiWZxkSzTkTTJYXZVU3rcWmDP5FtMTT@i3pgz/XD59lYbOqlLXf@8Nf7je37J8/)

The program does bignum arithmetic, as long as sed can store in memory the unary result.

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 18 Bytes

```
(gc 1)-join"+"|iex
```

this assumes the file is named '1' with no extension.

alternate 24 byte version, takes filename as input:

```
(gc "$args")-join"+"|iex
```

explanation:

`(` `g`et `c`ontent of the file `"$args"` `)` then `-join` the lines together with a `"+"` to form a valid-syntax sum, then `|` `i`nvoke `ex`pression to calculate it as if it was typed into the console directly.

if output is allowed in the following format:

```
Count    : 3
Average  :
Sum      : 227
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

then `gc 1|measure -s` is a valid 15 byte solution, thanks to @AdmBorkBork for pointing that out.

Comment: Your 18 byte version is valid.

Comment: @Lembik Thanks, wasn't 100% sure if the no-extension would be allowed, updated the answer there.

Comment: If extraneous output is allowed, you can do `gc 1|measure -s` for 15

Comment: @Lembik see AdmBorkBork's suggestion, if all the 'extra' text is allowed let me know and I can update my answer, thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is allowed but it is nice.

Comment: @Lembik thanks for clearing that up - i'll leave it as a note anyway as it is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 55 bytes

```
@set s=0
@for /f %%n in (%1)do @set/as+=%%n
@echo %s%
```

Takes the file to be summed as a command-line parameter.

Comment: Do you have to do `set s=0` in the beginning? It will work on the first run without it, won't it?

Comment: @KodosJohnson I'm not sure that's legal in code golf; as I recall the same applies to being able to call a function more than once without the caller resetting global variables to zero in between.

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB: 17 bytes

```
sum(dlmread('x'))
```

Assumes a file named 'x' in current directory. `dlmread` reads numeric values from a file using delimiters - if no delimiter is specified as the second argument, it will infer from the file type. It successfully infers `\n` as the delimiter in a file as specified by the question, then uses `sum` to add them up.

Answer (score 2):

### QBasic 4.5, <s>61</s> 59 bytes

Since QBasic isn't the greatest with streams, the input is assumed in a file called "a".

*Minus 2 bytes because @DLosc showed me an alternate syntax for one of QBasic's most iconic commands. Does QBasic really hold no secrets for you?*

```
OPEN"I",1,"a"
WHILE EOF(1)=0:INPUT#1,b$:x=x+VAL(b$)
WEND:?x
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 121 bytes

Java, but no C#? That will not do...

```c#
using C=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){int a=0,b;for(;int.TryParse(C.ReadLine(),out b);)a+=b;C.WriteLine(a);}}
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/nexus/cs-core#HcmxCsIwEADQvV9xY4IlFBUdjk5ZFYoKzpc2ykGbQC4VSum3R3F8vDILhzfY9r5I9pOxMUgcPfYjiUC3SqbMPXwiD3AlDkqvHDJQ29QOXzEp/NE80tJREq@suXkaLhy80nWcMziNmnatQ2ueibP/F2nctlLO1XFfHU7NFw)

Since this score is worse than Java's, we'd better provide a 95 byte context-less function also:

```c#
using C=System.Console;int S(){int a=0,b;for(;int.TryParse(C.ReadLine(),out b);)a+=b;return a;}
```

Formatted and commented:

```c#
using C=System.Console;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int a=0,b; // a is accumulator, b is tempory storage
        for(;int.TryParse(C.ReadLine(),out b);) // read a line, try to parse it as an integer (expects a trailing new-line)
            a+=b; // add to accumulator
        C.WriteLine(a); // print accumulator
    }
}
```

I was really hoping to have some code like the following:

```c#
int a=0,b=0,c;
for(;(c=C.Read())>0;)
    b=c<15?(a+=b)*0:b*10+c-48;
C.WriteLine(a);
```

But it just doesn't pay :(

Just for fun, the `try...catch` solution is also 121 bytes

```c#
using C=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){int a=0;try{for(;;)a+=int.Parse(C.ReadLine());}catch{}C.WriteLine(a);}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 4 bytes

3 bytes of code, +1 for `-r` flag.

```
$+g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@6@inf7/v6GRMZcpl6Xlf90iAA)

`$+g` is the standard "sum all inputs" program--read it as `fold-plus(arglist)`. Normally the arglist is taken from command-line arguments. The `-r` flag takes it from lines of stdin instead.

Answer (score 2):

## PostScript, 11

Consists of two files. 
File A: (2 bytes)

```
0[
```

File B: (8 bytes tokenized)

```
]{add}forall =
```

Invoke as: (1 byte for extra file)

```
$ gs a inputfile b
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the input format is also valid PostScript code that just pushes all the numbers on the stack.

This allows it to very cheaply create an array from them over which it can iterate, by using multiple files to place an initial value for the summation and the opening brace on the stack before the input file.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you do it in pdf too?

Comment: @Lembik I'll see, it's a bit harder to do actual computation in PDF since it only contains a subset of the operators and a bunch of security limitations.

Answer (score 2):

## Go, 146 bytes

```golang
package main
import("bufio";"os";"strconv")
func main(){
s:=bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
n:=0
for s.Scan(){m,_:=strconv.Atoi(s.Text())
n+=m
print(n)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 15 bytes

I have two versions to do this.  The first (and longest) is to specification.  This will work with non negative integers only.  A negative integer will be treated as a end of input, but zeros will be handled correctly.

```
O<u;Ii?;+...@._
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=Tzx1O0lpPzsrLi4uQC5f&input=MTIzCjUKOTkK&speed=20)
Expanded onto the cube

```
    O <
    u ;
I i ? ; + . . .
@ . _ . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

This essentially reads in an integer and the seperator.  If the separator is negative (EOF or negative) redirect up into a path that will remove two items from the stack, output the already summed results, grab a superfluous input and exit.  Otherwise if the input is non negative remove from the stack then sum.  This creates a rolling total.

The shorter (8 byte) non-compliant version will handle non-zero integers, but it treats 0 on the stack as the end of input.

```
@O;UI!W+
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=QE87VUkhVys=&input=MTIzCjUKOTk=&speed=20)

```
    @ O
    ; U
I ! W + . . . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 33 bytes

```
puts [expr [join [read stdin] +]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6taKgSCE6Kz8zTyG6KDUxRaG4JCUzL1ZBOzb2/39DI2MuUy5LSwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 109 Bytes

```java
import java.util.*;int x;int s(){Scanner a=new 
Scanner(System.in);while(a.hasNext())x+=a.nextInt();return x;}
```

[Try it!](https://tio.run/##LY6xDsIwDET3fIXHBEQkQAwo4gNYWDoiBhMicGncKnGhqOq3lyCx2L6zdO9qfOGq7QLXt@dMsWuTQF082ws1duGUbzBniB7GmVhgcL@ZtRkrj8whAR44vOGvdPXJEqIlNu79oCZotA/MpzCINmZYHtByuY9cpEtB@sQlcpq7/tqQhywoZb1aukFEYl1JIr6fL4Dpng2MCv6AthfblZ9o/cNHX@JtqWWcmtQ0rzdbtVP7/Rc)

Reads from System.in

Answer (score 2):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 19 bytes

```
{_?~A=Z|_Xp\p=p+!A!
```

### Explanation

```
{        DO infinitely
_?       Ask for user input, save as A$
~A=Z     IF input was nothing (Z$ = "")
|_Xp     THEN QUIT, printing the total
\p=p+    ELSE increase the total by
     A   the given input
    ! !  cast as a number
```

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```
SELECT 0a INTO n;BULK INSERT n FROM'd:n'SELECT SUM(a)FROM n
```

This is the kind of thing that SQL was designed to do, surprised there isn't already an answer for it. Tested on MS SQL 2012.

`SELECT 0a INTO n;` is slightly shorter than `CREATE TABLE n(a INT)`. Adding a zero row doesn't change the total.

Text file named `n` (no extension) is located in the current folder on the D: drive. `BULK INSERT` is shorter and easier than other file import options like `SELECT FROM OPENROWSET(BULK)` or `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp.exe'`.

Of course if *input is allowed via a pre-existing table*, [per our normal I/O standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341/70172), then this would be trivial (**19 bytes**):

```
SELECT SUM(a)FROM n
```

But of course this challenge is all about the IO...

Answer (score 2):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
©1Þ
```

I'm going to add a builtin for `©1` eventually (e.g. when I'm done working on [bitwise](//github.com/aaronryank/bitwise)). (Just kidding, I'm never going to get around to it.)

Explanation:

```
©1Þ
©1   consume all input as integers
  Þ  sum the entire stack
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@///QSsPD8/7/N@Qy4jLmMgEA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 8 bytes

```
?+
;,;!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/labyrinth#@2@vzWWtY63o8P@/oZExlymXpSUA)

The left-most 2x2 block is the main loop:

```
?   Read integer.
+   Add to running total (initially zero).
,   Read character. 10 as long as there is another input, -1 at EOF which will
    exit the loop.
;   Discard the 10.
```

Once we hit EOF, the IP moves east from the `,`.

```
;   Discard the -1.
!   Output the sum.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 111 bytes

```
import java.util.*;int c(){Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);int r=0;for(;c.hasNext();r+=c.nextInt());return r;}
```

Takes the input from STDIN.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#LY7NCsIwEITveYo9JgrBHzyU0AfwUC89iocYo0baTUk2VSl99pqAp9mPHWZmcf3gA8FLj1omcp1cKWY6HSM0EwNwSGC4mFqjEW0AU6N9w594@41ke@lQqGIM9UbdfeDKyKeOJ/shLlRY10Zivo@YMbOlFBCCmlnOH9K1cwYiacoyeneDXjvkLQWHj/MFtCgzAP5VPpEc8ot42dFwIU0JzZaZzcuy3e3ZgVXVDw)

Comment: Java, the black sheep of the golfing family :)

Comment: @Lembik Yep.. I can usually compete with BrainFuck, C# and other longer languages, but Java certainly will never win a golfing contest. The only accepted Java answer I've seen so far was for a [popularity-contest]. But it's still fun to golf in Java imo, and once in a while [something is pretty short compared to other submissions - in Java 8 that is](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113451/52210) :)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 124 bytes

```javascript
t=0;
r=require('readline').createInterface({input:process.stdin});
r.on('line',l=>{t-=-l});
r.on('close',()=>console.log(t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#Rcs9CsMwDEDh3RexDY3pDx3Souw9RnDUYhBSKitT6Nld06Xbg4/XDI53p6D43opi8IrzQoXRx5R7Gz7YUJ9zxrAXXje7rSoZa03VlsKf2O8kHPxvOhBMuw0w0B8ySe0SIkxZuAphInkFi7G10/nirm4cvw)

Comment: 119 bytes: `t=0;with(require('readline').createInterface({input:process.stdin}))on('line',l=>{t-=-l}),on('close',_=>console.log(t))`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You can do even better with chaining, so: [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113961/56183).

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 44 bytes

```
print(sum(map(s->parse(Int,s),readlines())))
```

Comment: A Julia answer is very warmly welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 24 bytes

```
p
/
+
j, ,']
1'[J-1
   0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jellyfish#@1/Apc@lzZWlo6CjHstlqB7tpWvIpaCgYPD/vyGXEZcxAA)

#### Explanation

Reading input isn't very flexible in Jellyfish. In particular, there's no easy way to read a variable number of integers from STDIN, except as a list literal. So the majority of this code is input.

The shortest way I've found is to read all of STDIN as a string, then wrap it in `[...]` and then evaluate the string. Thankfully, Jelly's parser only looks for whitespace as a separator in lists, not specifically for space characters. So the linefeed separation required by the challenge works.

So let's build up the code from the bottom:

```
   J-1
   0
```

Read all input.

```
   ,']
   J-1
   0
```

Append `]`.

```
 , ,']
 '[J-1
   0
```

Prepend `[`.

```
j, ,']
1'[J-1
   0
```

Evaluate.

```
/
+
j, ,']
1'[J-1
   0
```

Fold addition (in other words, sum).

```
p
/
+
j, ,']
1'[J-1
   0
```

Print the result.

Answer (score 1):

### C++, 99 Bytes

```
using namespace std;int main(){string a;int b=0;while(1){getline(cin,a);cout<<(b+=stoi(a))<<"\n";}}
```

Not my finest work, and there's probably a far better way to go about doing this. Still, I figured that using a string was the optimal way of doing things, seeing as I felt conversions with 'cin' would take up a vast majority of my code otherwise.

Enjoy!

Comment: You could save a few bytes by just wrapping the function in `namespace std{` and declaring the function as `::main`, rather than using `using`.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 48 bytes

```
print(io.Source.stdin.getLines.map(_.toInt).sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 112 bytes

Improvements upon [the other JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113753/56183) and comment below it.

```javascript
a=0
require('readline').createInterface({input:process.stdin}).on('line',l=>a+=+l).on('close',_=>console.log(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#JctNCsIwEEDhfS6ShErwBxcV0r2nkCEdJTDM1Jl0VTx7LLp7fPA65KNTfK9VMXhFmKky@pjK3g3v3FCfUDBslZe13RaVgmbJ2lz5E5Nw8L/jQHmCIQ/0t0JiOz7yVIRNCBPJK0CMvZ/OF3d14/gF)

Given the split module (`npm install split`), it's much shorter:

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org) with split module, 90 bytes

```javascript
a=0
process.stdin.pipe(require('split')()).on('data',l=>a+=+l).on('end',_=>console.log(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 47 bytes

```
s=0
pull n
do until n=''
  s=s+n
  pull n
  end
say s
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 11 bytes

```
/o
\i@/Hd&+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@fzxWT6aDvkaKm/f@/oZExlwGXKZelJQA)

This feels a bit suboptimal with all those mirrors (and also because the `H` could also be a `+`, possibly allowing reuse there), but so far I've only found a handful of different 11-byte solutions.

#### Explanation

```
/o
\i@/...
```

While it's sometimes possible to shorten it, this seems to be a good pattern for programs which a) one or more integers as input, b) transform them with a linear program in Cardinal mode (i.e. integer processing mode), c) want to output one integer. The instruction pointer (IP) first moves from `/` to `/` bouncing through the `i` which reads all input. Then the `...` is executed and the IP wrap around to the wrong. The `\` puts the IP again in Ordinal mode where `o` prints the integer as a decimal string and `@` terminates the program. So that's the framework I'm using here.

The core of the program is then just four commands:

```
H   Compute the absolute value of the top of the stack. The reason we're doing this
    is that the stack still holds the entire input as a string. But as soon as you
    try to pop a value in Cardinal mode, that string gets implicitly converted
    to the integers it contains. So in this case, the H itself doesn't really
    do anything but it forces the input to be converted. We could also use
    + here and already sum the top two values (if there's only one value it
    would get added to an implicit zero, so that's fine).
d   Push the stack depth, i.e. the number of integers in the input.
&   Execute the next command that many times.
+   Add the top two numbers of the stack. Of course this is one more addition
    than we need, but there are only implicit zeros beneath the input so
    they don't change the result.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 15 bytes

```
(\$]U]P.%p/+U(<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/XyNGJTY0NkBPtUBfO1TD5v9/QyNjLlMuS0sA)

Formats into this triangle:

```
    (
   \ $
  ] U ]
 P . % p
/ + U ( <
```

Explanation:

The IP starts from the top of the triangle, moving Southeast. So the first code that is executed is this:

```
($]
```

That simply reads integers as input until there is no more input.

This is how the interpreter sees the next part:

```
p(U+P]U%
```

- `p` pops the EOF from the stack.
- `(` opens a loop (to add the inputted integers).
- `U` pulls the "memory" (register) value onto the stack if it is not zero.
- `+` adds the top two stack values together, pops them, and pushes the result.
- `P` pops the top of stack into memory. Now, if we've added all inputted integers together, nothing will be on the stack.
- `]` ends the loop if the top of the stack is falsy  (or the stack is empty).
- `U` pulls the memory value onto the stack.
- `%` prints it.
- Another loop is created at the end of the code, but that doesn't do anything as the IP runs off the playing field and terminates.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 78 bytes

```javascript
process.stdin.on("data",r=>console.log((""+r).split`
`.reduce((a,v)=>+a+ +v)))
```

No `require`s needed for this one, just native NodeJS.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCgMhDADAu68ongxuA23pYQ@7b9mgoVjESGL9vp350iRLWvq4N8m8VldJbIY2cmkoLfhMg/ymx5mkmVTGKp8QvI8KaL2WcbkLlfMvcQi0TTjOSPEWJwCs9Xi@3Nvt@x8)

Answer (score 1):

### Dart, 96 bytes (non async), 132 bytes (async)

Non async:

```
import'dart:io';main(){_ s;_ i=0;while((s=stdin.readLineSync())!=null)i+=int.parse(s);print(i);}
```

Dart allows you to define local variables with types that don't exist when running in uncheck mode (which is the default mode). This program doesn't function in checked mode.

Async:

```
import'dart:io';import'dart:convert';main()async=>print((await UTF8.decodeStream(stdin)).split("\n").fold(0,(p,e)=>p+int.parse(e)));
```

The async version is longer, easier to read, and faster than the sync version. It also works in checked mode. UTF8.decodeStream decodes the entire stream into a Future, await waits for this to finish and gives a String, the string is split by line into List, and finally the strings are folded into the final result.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, <s>59 bytes</s> 57 bytes

New code: 57 bytes

```
i,s=0,0;repeat i,s=i+s,io.read("*l")until not s print(i)
```

We initialize i and s to 0. For each iteration, we add s to i and load in a new s from stdin. Lua has implicit string -> number coercions when doing numeric operations on a string.

---

Old code: 59 bytes

```
i=0;io.read("*a"):gsub(".-\n",function(g)i=i+g end)print(i)
```

Takes entire stdin and turns it into a string, gsubs over the entire string to extract lines, uses implicit number conversion and adds the lines to i, then prints i.

Answer (score 1):

## [Carrot](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/), 6 bytes

```
#^A
+
```

Note the trailing space after the `+`.

Explanation:

```
#   //Set the stack to the entire input
^   //Convert to operations mode
A\n //Split the stack into an array on a new line
+   //Add all the arguments of the array together
    //Implicitly output the result
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons I am doing the rewrite of Carrot. With the new lexer, the space after `+` would not be needed as it will be understood that `+` takes no arguments.

Comment: @Cowsquack Ah nice that'll be good.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 2 bytes

```
&+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/19N@/9/QyNjLlMuS0sA)

A Ly builtin that would beat the accepted answer if it wasn't a 2-byte builtin...

Answer (score 1):

## [q/kdb+](http://kx.com/download/), 14 bytes

**Solution:**

```
sum"J"$(0:)`:f
```

**Example:**

```
q)system "cat f" / check contents of file f
"123"
,"5"
"99"
q)sum"J"$(0:)`:f
227
```

**Explanation:**

Read in the file called `f`, cast to longs, sum up:

```
sum"J"$read0`:f / ungolfed solution
            `:f / our input file f
       read0    / read in a file, break on newlines
   "J"$         / parse strings to longs
sum             / sum it up
```

**Bonus:**

The solution in **K4** is **10 bytes**. Eequivalent to `` sum value each read0 `:f `` in **Q**:

```
+/.:'0:`:f
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```
I+0i.
O@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v/fU9sgU4/L3@H/f0MjYy4DLlMuS0sA)

#### Explanation

As long as there are numbers left to read, the program loops through the first line:

```
I   Read a decimal integer from STDIN.
+   Add it to the top of the stack. Initially, the stack is empty, which adds
    the first number to an implicit zero.
0   Push 0.
i   Read the next byte. If there are numbers left, this will be a 10 (for the
    separating linefeed). Otherwise, we're at EOF and this gives -1.
.   Jump to (0, x), where x is the byte we just read, modulo 2 (because the
    program is 2 rows tall). So for a linefeed, this jumps to the beginning
    of the first line, and at EOF this jumps to the beginning of the second
    line.
```

Once we run out of numbers to add, control flow goes to the second line:

```
O   Print the sum as a decimal integer.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), <s>16</s> 12 bytes

<sup>-4 bytes thanks to @JoKing</sup>

```
+>p*
^@
>&06
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcs7CsJQFEXRPgOxMFt457x/ExyJEBErUXH@cE27YD1fn/t7/0Ws2/e83K7LdkotIiFMplBpdAYTHShklFFBFTXU0UATJ3wc44wLrrjhjgee5BSXxx8) Requires the `-d` flag.

As a bonus, this works if no numbers are passed, and supports pretty much any separator other than digits and `-`.

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/X9uuQIsrzoHLTs3A7P9/QwMDLkMDIy5DU0PL/7opAA "Flobnar – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing I have no idea how that works, but ok...

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

Complete program.

```apl
+/⍎⍕⊃⎕NGET⍞1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@2/qPevke9Ux91NT/qm@rn7hryqHeeIUjuv2ZxhkJqcka@gqGRsYKdQl5pbrFeSUUJF1zcVMEOm7ClJYq4AhgUcMEEAA)

`⍞` read filename from stdin

`⊃⎕NGET`…`1` get native file content as list of strings

`⍕` stringify (puts two spaces between lines)

`⍎` execute (as APL code)

`+/` sum

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
wJ∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJ3SuKIkSIsIiIsIjYzXG4xMTEiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
wJ∑
w   # list
 J  # merge
  ∑ # sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sinclair ZX81 (16K only - probably*) File size according to EightyOne - 163** bytes (yes 163!) Byte count undetermined

Firstly, we should make our file, so using direct mode, type:

```
LET A=123
LET B=5
LET C=99
```

To make sure that they are there, print them to the screen, as follows:

```
PRINT A,,B,,C
```

This should appear on the display:

[image: ZX81 variable output]

Now, to save this to file (as the variable stack is saved along with other important memory locations used by the interpreter), simply type:

```
SAVE "SUM"
```

If you're using a real ZX81 then press play and record on tape, whilst emulators like EightyOne will create a tape image for you.

Now clear the RAMs with:

```
RAND USR 0
```

or:

```
NEW
```

Now rewind the tape (or the emulator should auto-detect and start the virtual tape from the beginning), and type:

```
LOAD "SUM"
```

So our *file* is back in memories, so we need to add it together. Simply:

```
PRINT A+B+C
```

And the answer is:

[image: The ZX81 final output]

*I specify 16K because any less and the ZX81 will typically rearrange the memory and this could affect the var stack (mostly to do with collapsing the DFILE), as the DFILE is static with 16K then this should be less of an issue.

**The ZX81 file is saving more than just the VAR stack of three whole variables above, and although each number appears to be an integer, the ZX81 is storing these variables as 24-bit floating point numbers rather than 1 byte integers.

Comment: Utterly brilliant . Let's not mention the spec :)

Comment: I'm confused what the actual code is. Is that `PRINT A+B+C` part of it? Would it be invalid then if there are more or less than 3 numbers?

Comment: The challenge seemed to specifically require a file, and to do that on a ZX81 you need to save your values somewhere. I decided to use the 24-bit floating point variables that I named `A`, `B`, and `C`. I could have `POKE`d these values to a spare bit of memory but I'm not sure if it'll save. So if you wanted more variables, then you'd need to initialise and declare more variables, so if `LET D=321` and that was `SAVE`d then to add up the file contents, one would `PRINT A+B+C+D`. I could save to a string but I'd been some way to separate each individual number by a comma, for instance.

Comment: Remember, I initialised and declared the variable values, then saved that to a file before clearing the memory. I then loaded back the file using the ZX81's equivalent of standard in - once the file was loaded, the variables were back in memory, so therefore I could use the `PRINT` keyword to add up and output the values.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers The same program needs to work for an arbitrary number of values without modification.

Comment: So how to create files and read them on a ZX81 then... Okay back to 101.

Comment: Also note that the program must use the input format specified in the question.

Comment: Sure but programming standards were very different in 1981 - standard in? `INPUT A` then.

Comment: This is why I suggested having one liners and golfing in the Retro Computing stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

## Anyfix, 4 bytes

```
ɦ€#S
```

#### Explanation

```
ɦ€#S  Program
ɦ     Exhaust input; read into a list of lines
 €    Map: 
  #        Parse to number
   S  Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```js
s=>eval(s.split`
`.join`+`)
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
s=>eval(s.split`
`.join`+`)
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value);o.innerText=f(i.value=`123\n5\n99`)
```

```css
textarea{font-family:sans-serif;height:100px;width:100px;}
```

```html
<textarea id=i></textarea><pre id=o>
```

---

### Explanation

- Takes input as a multiline string via parameter `s`.
- Splits the string to an array on newlines.
- Joins the array to a string on `+`.
- Evals the string to give us the sum.

---

### Alternative, 23 bytes

If we could take each integer as an individual argument of our function then we could do this:

```js
(...a)=>eval(a.join`+`)
```

---

### Alternative, 63 bytes

If we *have* to take a file name as input then use this version instead:

```js
p=>fetch(p).then(r=>r.text()).then(s=>eval(s.split`
`.join`+`))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
|+
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C%2B&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10&m=2)

Also prints intermediate results, which doesn't appear to be disallowed

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 98 bytes

```c++
#include<regex>
namespace std{int::main(){istream_iterator<int>a{cin},b;cout<<accumulate(a,b,0);}}
```

### Ungolfed

```c++
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istream_iterator<int> first{std::cin};
    std::istream_iterator<int> last{};
    std::cout << std::accumulate(first, last, 0);
}
```

We have `std::istream_iterator` to read input as whitespace-separated integers, and `std::accumulate` to add them up.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 13 bytes

```
~Ilj~#
 >K+O@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/7/OMyerTplLwc5b29/h/39DI2MuUy5LSwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Scheme, 48 bytes

```scm
(write(let l((x 0))(if(real? x)(+(l(read))x)0)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYlBCoAwDATvfUWPG0SwzQN8i9RIi9FDLdjfRwVh5jDMlbIcMqZc0i6nGe5amkCleQW6n4hQNlRZdPadMEC/WIk6vY/MYnD8GgO7EPnHcXgA) (Chicken Scheme, but this works on other schemes as well)

`(write ... )` write to STDOUT the result of

- `(let l ... )` looping special form named `l`
- - `((x 0))` initially declare `x` as `0`
- - `(if ... )` if
- - - `(real? x)` `x` is real, i.e. not EOF,
- - - `(+ ... )` add
- - - - `(l(read))` the result of this loop called with `x` set as the value read from STDIN
- - - - `x` with x
- - - `0` else give `0`

Answer (score 0):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 24 bytes

```
[]{{}[<><<>()>]{}}[<>()]
```

#### Run example

```
$ printf "11\n12\n13" | ./flurry -nii -c "[]{{}[<><<>()>]{}}[<>()]"
36
```

The integer input mode handles the input format requirement. Then it is straightforward reduction over the stack.

```haskell
// Reduce the stack by running <pop and add to the current value>
// <stack height> times
main = height pop_add 0
height = []
pop_add = \x. x succ pop = {{}[<><<>()>]{}} // add x y = x succ y
0 = (SK) = [<>()]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 13 bytes

Port of [Daniero’s Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113738/11261).

```ruby
:sum+Z|-:p^$<
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBgqWlJWm6FmutiktztaNqdK0K4lRsIGJQqQUrDY2MuUy5LC25IAIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 18 bytes

```
1#.0".&>;:@stdin''
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxyVBZz0BJT83O2sqhuCQlM09dHSKxQpMrNTkjXyENwl2wwtDImMuUy9ISwgcA)

```
1#.0".&>;:@stdin''
           stdin''  NB. self-explanatory
          @         NB. then
        ;:          NB. split into words, J boxes each int and each LF
      &>            NB. for every box
   0".              NB. eval the item as J code and fallback to 0
1#.                 NB. sum the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
¤
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhaLDi1ZUpyUXAzlLlhhaGTMZcplaQnhAwA)

Or, **2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)** flagless:

```
¤S
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWiw8tCV5SnJRcDOUvWGFoZMxlymVpCeEDAA)